# subtract two times in python

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I have two `datetime.time` values, `exit` and `enter` and I want to do something like:

```
duration = exit - enter
```

However, I get this error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and
>   'datetime.time

How do I do this correctly? One possible solution is converting the `time` variables to `datetime` variables and then subtruct, but I'm sure you guys must have a better and cleaner way.

Answer (score 129):

Try this:

```
from datetime import datetime, date

datetime.combine(date.today(), exit) - datetime.combine(date.today(), enter)
```

`combine` builds a datetime, that can be subtracted.

Comment: To @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams point, one could use, say,`datetime(1,1,1,0,0,0)` instead of `date.today()`.

Comment: Don't name a `datetime` `exit`, since `exit` is a built-in function.

Comment: using python 2.7, I don't have `combine` method in my `datetime` module:  
`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'combine'`

Comment: mtoloo: There is `datetime` module and it has a `datetime` object inside. The object inside has `combine` method. If you are simply importing `datetime` (like this: `import datetime`), then what you need to do later is this `datetime.datetime.combine`.

Comment: or date.min -> datetime.date(1, 1, 1)

Comment: There is a very rare case when you call this function at some time like 23:59:59:9999. In that case, the `date.today()`  before and the `date.today()` later will return a different value. It would be better to give the value `date.today()` to a variable.

Comment: If the purpose is to determine the duration from time X to time Y, with the understanding that "time Y" is *the next time* that the clock shows that time, be careful that the time could pass midnight in between X and Y. If the above calculation gives a negative result, depending on your application, it may be correct to add 24 hours.

Answer (score 69):

Use:

```
from datetime import datetime, date

duration = datetime.combine(date.min, end) - datetime.combine(date.min, beginning)
```

Using `date.min` is a bit more concise and works even at midnight.

This might not be the case with `date.today()` that might return unexpected results if the first call happens at 23:59:59 and the next one at 00:00:00.

Answer (score 59):

instead of using time try timedelta:

```
from datetime import timedelta

t1 = timedelta(hours=7, minutes=36)
t2 = timedelta(hours=11, minutes=32)
t3 = timedelta(hours=13, minutes=7)
t4 = timedelta(hours=21, minutes=0)

arrival = t2 - t1
lunch = (t3 - t2 - timedelta(hours=1))
departure = t4 - t3

print(arrival, lunch, departure)
```

Comment: Thanks. This is very clean and better than all the answers here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096953/how-to-calculate-the-time-interval-between-two-time-strings/3096984

Comment: Note that `timedelta` conceptually represents a span of time, not a time of day.

Comment: Note that`timedelta` conceptually represents a span of time and not a point in time, which makes it the correct thing to use here, as we are implicitly talking about the time that has passed (a delta of time) since the start of the day (a point in time).

Answer (score 10):

You have two datetime.time objects so for that you just create two timedelta using datetime.timedetla and then substract as you do right now using "-" operand. Following is the example way to substract two times without using datetime.

```
enter = datetime.time(hour=1)  # Example enter time
exit = datetime.time(hour=2)  # Example start time
enter_delta = datetime.timedelta(hours=enter.hour, minutes=enter.minute, seconds=enter.second)
exit_delta = datetime.timedelta(hours=exit.hour, minutes=exit.minute, seconds=exit.second)
difference_delta = exit_delta - enter_delta
```

**difference_delta** is your difference which you can use for your reasons.

Comment: It is possible to convert the timedelta object back to datetime ? I mean we have difference_delta .seconds(), is there any way to get back a datetime or time object ? Thx

Comment: Yes.  `datetime.min + delta`

Answer (score 9):

The python [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) library should do what you need. A `timedelta` is returned when you subtract two `datetime` instances.

```
import datetime
dt_started = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

# do some stuff

dt_ended = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
print((dt_ended - dt_started).total_seconds())
```

Answer (score 7):

`datetime.time` can not do it - But you could use `datetime.datetime.now()`

```
start = datetime.datetime.now()
sleep(10)
end = datetime.datetime.now()
duration = end - start
```

Answer (score 4):

`datetime.time` does not support this, because it's nigh meaningless to subtract times in this manner. Use a full `datetime.datetime` if you want to do this.

Comment: If you know from your domain that two `datetime.time` objects `a` and `b` are from the same day, and that `b > a`, then the operation `b - a` has perfect meaning.

Comment: Even if they aren't the same day, it still makes fine sense. At least as much sense as `arctan(0) = (0, pi, 2pi, ...)`, but we just don't care about any of those values after the first. So, `4:00 - 20:00` is `8:00` - it's also (`32:00`, `56:00`, ... ), but who cares?

Comment: [Unless it's one of those cases that doesn't.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY)

Comment: Furthermore, Python doesn't even stay consistent. If a - b is meaningless for two time objects, then how it that a > b or a < b behaves as it does? The comparison is already assuming same day, otherwise it is completely broken. Since the assumption is made for comparison, it is entirely consistent to make the same assumption for difference operations.

Comment: Saying it's meaningless is subjective, but I see where you're coming from. Adding two times together seems to be a meaningless representation to me. I think subtracting two time values should return a timedelta. If that timedelta happens to be negative, so be it. What I want to know is why python can't add or subtract a timedelta from a time to return a new time value.

Answer (score 4):

```
import datetime

def diff_times_in_seconds(t1, t2):
    # caveat emptor - assumes t1 & t2 are python times, on the same day and t2 is after t1
    h1, m1, s1 = t1.hour, t1.minute, t1.second
    h2, m2, s2 = t2.hour, t2.minute, t2.second
    t1_secs = s1 + 60 * (m1 + 60*h1)
    t2_secs = s2 + 60 * (m2 + 60*h2)
    return( t2_secs - t1_secs)

# using it
diff_times_in_seconds( datetime.datetime.strptime( "13:23:34", '%H:%M:%S').time(),datetime.datetime.strptime( "14:02:39", '%H:%M:%S').time())
```

Answer (score 4):

`timedelta` accepts negative(-) time values. so it could be simple as below.

**Answer (single line, without date combine)**

```
datetime.timedelta(hours=exit.hour-enter.hour, minutes=exit.minute-enter.minute)
```

---

**Run test**

```
import datetime

enter = datetime.time(hour=1, minute=30)
exit = datetime.time(hour=2, minute=0)
duration = datetime.timedelta(hours=exit.hour-enter.hour, minutes=exit.minute-enter.minute)

>>> duration
datetime.timedelta(seconds=1800)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had similar situation as you and I ended up with using external library called [arrow](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Here is what it looks like:

```py
>>> import arrow
>>> enter = arrow.get('12:30:45', 'HH:mm:ss')
>>> exit = arrow.now()
>>> duration = exit - enter
>>> duration
datetime.timedelta(736225, 14377, 757451)
```

Comment: Here you are just demonstrating subtracting complete datetime objects, not times-of-day as in the original question

Answer (score 2):

```
import time
from datetime import datetime

def calcTime(enter,exit):
    format="%H:%M:%S"
    #Parsing the time to str and taking only the hour,minute,second 
    #(without miliseconds)
    enterStr = str(enter).split(".")[0]
    exitStr = str(exit).split(".")[0]
    #Creating enter and exit time objects from str in the format (H:M:S)
    enterTime = datetime.strptime(enterStr, format)
    exitTime = datetime.strptime(exitStr, format)
    return exitTime - enterTime

enter = datetime.today().time()
#Sleeping for 5 seconds before initializing the exit variable
time.sleep(5)
exit = datetime.today().time()
duration = calcTime(enter,exit)
print(f"Duration is {duration} (Hours:Minutes:Seconds)")
#Output: Duration is 0:00:05 (Hours:Minutes:Seconds)
```

If it is helpful, you can use the calcTime function as shown.