# timezone aware vs. timezone naive in python

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I am working with datetime objects in python. I have a function that takes a time and finds the different between that time and now.

```
def function(past_time):
    now = datetime.now()
    diff = now - past_time
```

When I initialized past_time before passing it to this function I initialized it as datetime naive. And now is also a datetime naive object. However when I try to call this function I get the error: can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes. How come this is the case if they are both theoretically datetime naive objects?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think maybe this link can help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259882/subtract-two-times-in-python "Use the `combine` to builds a datetime, that can be subtracted. "

Comment: Pardon but meanwhile perhaps we might want to consider the definition of "naive": _(of a person or action) showing a lack of experience, wisdom, or judgment._ It is not the opposite of aware. So the correct and logical term would be "timezone unaware". Developers of datetime, pytz etc please correct this going forward.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

datetime doesn't do any cross time zone calculations, because it's a complex and involved subject.

I suggest converting dates to UTC universally and performing maths on those.

I recently completed a project using timezones in a large python/Django project and after investigation went with converting everything internally to UTC and converting only on display to the user.

You should look into [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) to do the conversions to/from UTC, and store Olson codes for the timezones you want in your app - perhaps associated with each user, or appropriate to your program.

Comment: Okay great. That makes sense. I am new to django and working with datetime objects... could you point me towards more information about doing those conversions? Thanks!

Comment: Added a note for pytz which is what I used.

Comment: Were you able to use the information to do what you wanted? If so, could you click to accept the answer? Thanks!

Comment: This was right at the time of the answer, but absolutely wrong now.

Answer (score 1):

Use :

```
    now = now.replace(tzinfo=past_time.tzinfo)
```

before diff = now - past_time.

so that both now and past_time have same tzinfo.

only if now and past_time intended to be in same timezone.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this post and wanted to give you an alternative answer (I know it was originally posted in 2016!)

I have a UTC aware date on an object (in my case an RDS snapshot). I needed  to compare this with a naive variable.

I want to process snapshots older than `days_ago` days old for the supplied `current_date`, time=00:01, and timezone=+00:00

e.g.
If...
`current_date` is 2023-11-08 11:10:04.123456
`days_ago` is 30
I want the `cut_off_date` to be 2023-10-11 00:01:00.000000+00:00

Here are the steps:

1. Create a UTC aware variable `cut_off_date`
2. Create a timezone variable `utc_tzinfo` which has an offset of 0 hours
3. Set `cut_off_date` to be the supplied date - 30 days
4. Set the time to 00:01
5. Set the timezone to be `utc_tzinfo`

```
        # Calculate the cutoff date for deleting backups.
        # this needs to be UTC aware, so has to have a timezone. Which is UTC or +00:00
        utc_offset = datetime.timedelta(hours=0)
        utc_tzinfo = datetime.timezone(utc_offset)

        # create cut off date, for 00:01 in the morning, and timezone of UTC
        cut_off_date = current_date - datetime.timedelta(days=days_ago)
        cut_off_date = cut_off_date.replace(hour=19, minute=1, second=0, microsecond=0)
        cut_off_date = cut_off_date.replace(tzinfo=utc_tzinfo)

        # now you can compare a TZ aware variable with your chosen time
```