# How to substract date with Timezone or how to delete timezone on date?

Tags: python, api, twitter

I'm beginner with python.
I'm using the twitter API with tweepy for a school project that aims to retrieve information from users whose username I enter. Moreover I want to calculate the age of the account by subtracting the current date from the date of creation of the twitter account that I get via the API. However I have the error message :
**TypeError: can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes**

```
tweets = item.statuses_count
account_created_date = item.created_at
delta = datetime.utcnow() - account_created_date
account_age_days = delta.days
print("Account age (in days): " + str(account_age_days))
if account_age_days > 0:
    print("Average tweets per day: " + "%.2f"%(float(tweets)/float(account_age_days)))
```

The format of the creation date of the account that I retrieve is as follows:

```
Created_account_date : 2009-06-02 20:12:29+00:00
```

I suppose the problem comes from the timezone but I'm not sure at all and I don't know how to do it. I thought of using replace() to delete the timezone but I can't perform any action on the variable of the account creation date.

I found a lot of answers on the internet but they don't work/or I don't understand them

Would you have a solution please?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999226/timezone-aware-vs-timezone-naive-in-python