# How to calculate the difference between dates in python

Tags: python, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I subtract a day from a python date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441147/how-can-i-subtract-a-day-from-a-python-date)
>   [subtract two times in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259882/subtract-two-times-in-python)

I had generated date in python as below

```
import time
time_stamp = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

print time_stamp
```

Result:

```
'2012-12-19'
```

What i am trying is, if above time_stamp is the present today's date , i want a date `'2012-12-17'` by performing difference(substraction of two days)

So how to perform date reduction of two days from the current date in python

Comment: use the datetime library and datetime objects.   datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 17, 00) - datetime.timedelta(days=2)

Comment: What have you tried? Did you check the datetime API and especially the timedelta API?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/5259882/114147

Answer (score 1):

To perform calculations between some dates in Python use the `timedelta` class from the `datetime` module.

To do what you want to achieve, the following code should suffice.

```
import datetime

time_stamp = datetime.datetime(day=21, month=12, year=2012)

difference = time_stamp - datetime.timedelta(day=2)

print '%s-%s-%s' % (difference.year, difference.year, difference.day)
```

**Explanation of the above:**

- The second line creates a new `datetime` object (from the the `datetime class`), with specified *day, month and year*
- The third line creates a `timedelta` object, which is used to perform calculations between datetime objects