# Difference between two time instances

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.x

I have to read two columns of data from an Excel file, then calculate the difference between each pair and write the answer in a new column in Excel. There is no problem in reading and writing data but I could not subtract two `datetime.time` objects from each other.

My data is in the format `"16:56:20.09"` and when I try to find the difference between two of them I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'
```

Could you please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [subtract two times in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259882/subtract-two-times-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't subtract `time` instances, because there's no definitive ordering to them; what's the difference between 12.00 and 13.00? An hour? What if I now tell you I mean 12.00 yesterday and 13.00 tomorrow? Hence the error:

```
>>> from datetime import date, time, datetime
>>> t1 = time(12, 00)
>>> t2 = time(13, 00)
>>> t1 - t2

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    t1 - t2
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'
```

You need to know *what day the times occur on* to calculate the difference. You need to convert them to `datetime` objects by [combining them](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine) with the appropriate `date`:

```
>>> dt1 = datetime.combine(date(2015, 7, 14), t1)
>>> dt2 = datetime.combine(date(2015, 7, 16), t2)
```

Now you *can* subtract them:

```
>>> dt2 - dt1
datetime.timedelta(2, 3600)  # two days, 3,600 seconds
```

---

If they're on the same day (or you're assuming they are), it generally* doesn't matter *which* day, so you can do e.g.

```
>>> datetime.combine(date.today(), t2) - datetime.combine(date.today(), t1)
datetime.timedelta(0, 3600)  # one hour
```

* *(i.e. ignoring changing clocks, leap seconds, ...)*