# Python - difference between time

Tags: python, datetime

Looking for easiest way to calculate the difference between 2 python times and display the millisecond delta

I have 2 times

```
startTime = datetime.datetime.now().time()
```

do some stuff...

```
endTime= datetime.datetime.now().time()
```

This works fine and when I log the times out and I get something like this in my logs...

```
RequestStartTime = 08:56:19.188999

ResponseTime = 08:56:19.905999
```

When I try to simply subtract them like this

```
delta = endTime - startTime
```

I get the following error

```
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'time' and 'time'
```

All I want to do is show the difference in microseconds and I can't figure it out

I want to show is `717000 ms`

Comment: turn them into milliseconds and then subtract.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just use the result of `now()`, and don't convert them to `time`s, you can take the difference & extract the bits you want in the form you want; for example:

```
startTime = datetime.datetime.now()
endTime= datetime.datetime.now()
delta = endTime - startTime
print str(delta).split(":")[2]
```

Comment: you may get a wrong result during DST transitions. Use `utcnow()` + `.total_seconds()` or `time.monotonic()` (short intervals) instead.

Comment: This works great, thanks but now I am only getting microseconds.  so for example when I have these 2 times like14:25:52.206000 and 14:25:55.539000 I get a difference of 333000 which is the microseconds but I am not getting the 3 seconds, (55 - 52), included in that.  Is there an easy way to do that all in one fell swoop?

Comment: I can do it as follows but seems this way is harder than it should be  `seconds = str((endTime - startTime).seconds)`   `microseconds = str((endTime - startTime).microseconds)`    `infolog(seconds+"."+microseconds)`

Comment: @Stiley: as I said above, you could use `seconds = (end_time - start_time).total_seconds()`, to get seconds including microseconds (as a fraction). To get milliseconds directly, use: `milliseconds = (end - start) / timedelta(milliseconds=1)` as shown in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32358658/4279)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
from datetime import datetime, date

datetime.combine(date.today(), endTime) - datetime.combine(date.today(), startTime)
```

Hope this Helps.

Comment: Will this work if the program starts at 11:59:55 PM on tuesday, and finishes on 12:00:05 AM on wednesday?

Comment: @Kevin: `abs()` call may fix the overnight difference.

Comment: @Kevin obviously it won't work. The question assumes two time instances on the same day.

Answer (score 1):

To measure the difference manually, you should use [`time.monotonic()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.monotonic) instead.

If you don't care about leap seconds (~1s error once per year and a half) and you need to display the local time:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

start = datetime.now(timezone.utc).astimezone() # current local time
# print("RequestStartTime = %s" % start.time())
end = datetime.now(timezone.utc).astimezone()
diff_milliseconds = (end - start) / timedelta(milliseconds=1)
print("%.0f ms" % diff_milliseconds)
```

The code works fine around/during DST transitions.

Note: it is different from the code that uses just `.now()`. If you use  `.now()` (no argument) then you get a naive datetime object that represents local time and in that case if a DST transition happens between `start` and `end` times then `end - start` returns a completely wrong result i.e., the code may be wrong by an hour approximately couple of times per year in some timezones.

Answer (score 0):

the reason why you are getting an error is because class `time` does not support subtraction. You must turn `time` into miliseconds (int format) to subtract from one another.

instead of using `datetime`, use `time`

```
import time

def timenow():
    return int(round(time.time() * 1000))

startTime = timenow()
time.sleep(1)
endTime = timenow()

delta = endTime - startTime
print delta
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to convert the datetime objects to timestamps and subtract those. If you use Python 3.3 or later you can simply do something along these lines

```
startTime = datetime.datetime.now(timezone.utc).timestamp()
...
endTime = datetime.datetime.now(timezone.utc).timestamp()
```

Then you can just subtract those.

In Python 2 you do not have the timestamp method available. One way around would be to use a timedelta object:

```
startTime = datetime.datetime.now(timezone.utc)
...
endTime = datetime.datetime.now(timezone.utc)
dt = (endTime - startTime).total_seconds()
```

A third option is to simply use raw timestamps with `time.time()` and subtract them to get the time interval in seconds and fraction of seconds.

To be extra safe you could use `time.monotonic()` as @Sebastian mentions.

Comment: you should call `time.time()` instead (`.now().timestamp()` may fail during DST transitions). Note: both results may be inaccurate due to ntp-adjustments or around a leap second. You could [use `time.monotonic()` in this case](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32358658/4279)

Comment: Excellent points, @Sebastian. I have updated my answer to use UTC. Of course the issue with leap second adjustment remains.

Comment: `utcnow().timestamp()` is wrong unless the local timezone has zero utc offset. `.microseconds` is wrong if the difference is larger than a second (you could use `.total_seconds()` instead)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: you are totally right about ```.microseconds```! I have changed my answer to reflect that, thank you. Could you please expand on why a difference in timestamps would be incorrect when using ```.utcnow```? Thanks

Comment: `.timestamp()` uses local timezone for naive datetime objects (that may make the absolute values wrong). Local timezone may have different utc offsets at different times (that makes the difference wrong)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian you sir are right again! I have learned something today. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the best answer for this problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39651061/2686243

```
from datetime import datetime, date

duration = datetime.combine(date.min, end) - datetime.combine(date.min, beginning)
```