# Time formatting in Python Pandas

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, pandas, datetime-format

I've an Excel file having time in `mm:ss.0` format. I formatted this into `[h]:mm:ss;@` in Excel. How can this be done in Pandas?

Time : `58:44.1` in mm:ss.0 format yields a result `7:58:44` in [h]:mm:ss;@ format in Excel after formatting.

For example:

```
Input      Desired Output
58:44.1    7:58:44
07:53.3    8:07:53
46:59.6    9:47:00
20:14.0    10:20:14
50:58.7    11:50:59
19:50.0    12:19:50
41:53.5    13:41:53
```

Comment: So you just want add hour component, increment it and drop the `.0` correct?

Comment: @EdChum - Yes, exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can slice the string using vectorised [`str`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#string-handling) method, then construct `datetime` using [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas.to_datetime) from this passing the format string and add a `TimedeltaIndex` to it and then access the `time` component using [`dt.time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.time.html#pandas.Series.dt.time):

```
In [199]:
df['Desired Output'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['Input'].str[:-2], format='%M:%S') + pd.TimedeltaIndex(np.arange(7, 7 + len(df)), 'h')).dt.time
df

Out[199]:
     Input Desired Output
0  58:44.1       07:58:44
1  07:53.3       08:07:53
2  46:59.6       09:46:59
3  20:14.0       10:20:14
4  50:58.7       11:50:58
5  19:50.0       12:19:50
6  41:53.5       13:41:53
```

You can see that the dtype for Desired Output is not `datetime.time`:

```
In [201]:
df['Desired Output'].iloc[0]

Out[201]:
datetime.time(7, 58, 44)
```

Comment: How can I make the Desired Output as `datetime.time` since I need to find duration of two such input times?

Comment: Sorry it is `datetime.time` as I showed in the last line of code

Comment: In my result it is still an object type.

Comment: That's correct, you can see though that when you look at a single row values that the dtype is `datetime.time`

Comment: I got two columns namely desiredOutput1 and desiredOutput2 in the format that you've given. I, now, want to calculate the time difference between the two which I'm unable to with an error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'`

Comment: Please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259882/subtract-two-times-in-python basically you can't perform subtractions with datetime.time, you can with datetime or you can use combine

Comment: I tried subtraction for datetime and got these results for the following inputs:
`Time 1      Time 2        Difference
8:59:45 9:27:30  -1 days +23:27:45
9:52:29 10:08:54 -1 days +23:16:26`

But the desired output is `00:27:45  and 00:16:26` respectively

Comment: Unfortunately this is documented behaviour, also if you have another question please post another question rather than request further assistance via comments you will find that this is a common problem