# calculate difference between two time in hour

Tags: python, sql, django

I want to calculate difference between two time in hours using `django` in `sql db` the time are stored in timefield.

I tried this:

```
def DesigInfo(request):  # attendance summary
  emplist = models.staff.objects.values('empId', 'name')
  fDate = request.POST.get('fromDate')
  tDate = request.POST.get('toDate')

  if request.GET.get('empId_id'):
    sel = attendance.objects.filter(empId_id=request.GET.get('empId_id'),)
    for i in sel:
        # print i.
        # print   i.outTime
        # print i.inTime.hour,i.inTime.minute,i.inTime.second - i.outTime.hour,i.outTime.minute,i.outTime.second
        ss = i.inTime.hour
        ss1 = 12 - ss
        mm = i.outTime.hour
        mm1 = (12 + mm) - 12
        print ss1 + mm1
```

Comment: you can use any `time` or `datetime` module, instead of reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 3):

Since `i.inTime` and `i.outTime` are [time](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#time-objects) objects you cannot simply subtract them. A good approach is to convert them to [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) adding the date part (use today() but it is irrelevant to the difference), then subtract obtaining a [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) object.

```
delta = datetime.combine(date.today(), i.outTime) - datetime.combine(date.today(), i.inTime)
```

(Look here: [subtract two times in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259882/subtract-two-times-in-python))

Then if you want to express `delta` in hours:

```
delta_hours = delta.days * 24 + delta.seconds / 3600.0
```

A timedelta object has 3 properties representing 3 different resolutions for time differences (days, seconds and microseconds). In the last expression I avoided to add the microseconds but I suppose it is not relevant in your case. If it is also add `delta.microseconds / 3600000000.0`
Note that simply dividing seconds by 3600 would have returned only the integer part of hours avoiding fractions. It depends on your business rules how to round it up (round, floor, ceil or leave the fractional part as I did)

Comment: suppose time1=10:54:25 and time2=05:22:23 and we calculate ans=timet2-time1  like    ss = i.inTime.hour
        ss1 = 12 - ss
        mm = i.outTime.hour
        mm1 = (12 + mm) - 12
        print ss1 + mm1   but problem to calculate minut or second

Comment: As already stated. Do not try to reinvent the wheel: basic types already have methods to obtain time differences. Since I understand that your variables are not datetime objects but time objects I'll adapt the answer.

Comment: giving negative ans if outTime < startTime(i.e outTime = 05:00 and startTime= 13:00)

Answer (score 1):

Using datetime objects: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

A good stack overflow post on the topic [How to get current time in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415511/how-to-get-current-time-in-python?rq=1)

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
# wait some time
then = ... some time
# diff is a datetime.timedelta instance
diff = then - now
diff_hours = diff.seconds / 3600
```

Comment: dude but actually i were stored only time into database using Timefield()

Comment: That's ok.  You can use datetime.datetime.strptime to convert from a string to a time object

Answer (score 1):

You might want to play with this codes:

```
from datetime import datetime

#set the date and time format
date_format = "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S"

#convert string to actual date and time
time1  = datetime.strptime('8-01-2008 00:00:00', date_format)
time2  = datetime.strptime('8-02-2008 01:30:00', date_format)

#find the difference between two dates
diff = time2 - time1


''' days and overall hours between two dates '''
print ('Days & Overall hours from the above two dates')
#print days
days = diff.days
print (str(days) + ' day(s)')

#print overall hours
days_to_hours = days * 24
diff_btw_two_times = (diff.seconds) / 3600
overall_hours = days_to_hours + diff_btw_two_times
print (str(overall_hours) + ' hours');



''' now print only the time difference '''
''' between two times (date is ignored) '''

print ('\nTime difference between two times (date is not considered)')

#like days there is no hours in python
#but it has seconds, finding hours from seconds is easy
#just divide it by 3600

hours = (diff.seconds) / 3600  
print (str(hours) + ' Hours')


#same for minutes just divide the seconds by 60

minutes = (diff.seconds) / 60
print (str(minutes) + ' Minutes')

#to print seconds, you know already ;)

print (str(diff.seconds) + ' secs')
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way through I achieve is the comment of Zac given above. I was using relativedelta like this

```
from dateutil import relativedelta
difference = relativedelta.relativedelta( date1, date2)
no_of_hours = difference.hours
```

but it did not give me correct result when the days changes. So, I used the approach expressed above:

```
no_of_hours = (difference.days * 24) + (difference.seconds / 3600)
```

Please note that you will be getting negative value if date2 is greater than date1. So, you need to swipe the position of date variables in relativedelta.