# How to calculate difference between two values in two different rows

Tags: python, database, postgresql

I have some tables in postgresql database  with historical data such as following sample:

```
 log_id  |       login_time    |       logout_time       
----------+---------------------+---------------------
12885913 | 2016-03-01 05:10:59 | 2016-03-01 09:40:46
12886931 | 2016-03-01 09:41:51 | 2016-03-01 12:44:49
12887276 | 2016-03-01 12:45:54 | 2016-03-01 13:42:18
```

I want to calculate difference between logout_time of each row with next login_time and save it as login time interval. This table is result of python script that connect to postgresql 9.1 and extract these data from other tables and I want to find a solution with python for this issue.

Comment: this should help after extracting your data http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259882/subtract-two-times-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window function:

```
create table log_times (
    log_id int,
    login_time timestamp,
    logout_time timestamp
);

insert into log_times (log_id, login_time, logout_time) 
values 
(12885913, '2016-03-01 05:10:59', '2016-03-01 09:40:46'),
(12886931, '2016-03-01 09:41:51', '2016-03-01 12:44:49'),
(12887276, '2016-03-01 12:45:54', '2016-03-01 13:42:18')
;

select 
    *, 
    login_time - lag(logout_time) over (order by log_id) 
from log_times;
```

Result:

```
  log_id  |     login_time      |     logout_time     | ?column? 
----------+---------------------+---------------------+----------
 12885913 | 2016-03-01 05:10:59 | 2016-03-01 09:40:46 | 
 12886931 | 2016-03-01 09:41:51 | 2016-03-01 12:44:49 | 00:01:05
 12887276 | 2016-03-01 12:45:54 | 2016-03-01 13:42:18 | 00:01:05
(3 rows)
```