# DateTimeField & TimeField Error

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

My code is working perfectly working fine but due to my change in requirements I had to make DateTimeField to TimeField but after making the changes in my code I faced following error.

**Exception Value:  unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'**

My code is about salary calculation.

```
class salary(models.Model):
#employee = models.ForeignKey('employee', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
base_salary = models.IntegerField(default=0)
time_in = models.DateTimeField(default=tz.now, null=True, blank=True)
time_out = models.DateTimeField(default=tz.now, null=True, blank=True)
total_salary = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='0')

def calculate_salary(self):
    worked_hours = (self.time_out - self.time_in).total_seconds() / 60 / 60
    overtime_hours = 0

    # make sure you use timezone aware objects
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/timezones/#naive-and-aware-datetime-objects
    same_day_8pm = self.time_out.replace(hour=16, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
    if self.time_out > same_day_8pm:
        overtime_hours = (self.time_out - same_day_8pm).total_seconds() / 60 / 60

    salary_1 = worked_hours * self.base_salary
    salary_2 = overtime_hours * self.base_salary * 0.2
    total_salary = salary_1 + salary_2

    # careful: this will be a 'float', not an 'int'
    # with round() using 0 decimal digits you get an 'int'
    # total_salary = round(total_salary, 0)

    return total_salary

def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
    # are you really sure that you want to save a string ???
    self.total_salary = str(self.calculate_salary())
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: If your shift started at 11pm and ended at 6am, how many hours would you have worked per your code above?

Comment: @Alexander 7 hours

Comment: Not by your code:  6 (end time) - 23 (start time) = -17 hours.  Hence one of the reasons you cannot simply difference time.  Another reason is if the period in question lasted more than 24 hours, although that is relevant in your case.

Comment: but i have date field too  @Alexander im using RFID for timein timeout and it provides me date aslo but i dont know how to combine date & time together ...so i'm removing datetimefield

Comment: You should probably post the full stack trace of the error.  I had assumed it was caused by this: `(self.time_out - self.time_in)`

Comment: My code is working perfectly working fine but due to my change in requirements I had to make DateTimeField to TimeField but after making the changes in my code I faced following error.

Exception Value: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time' @Alexander

Comment: actually i recently started with python so dont understand half of the things so can you please help me solve the error @Alexander

Comment: Have you tried looking at my answer?  There is example code in responses to the linked question

Comment: You should post your _non-working_ code and the minimal amount of information to reproduce your error. [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python `datetime.datetime` objects can be subtracted, but `datetime.time` objects can't.  You can subtract them by combining them into `datetime` objects using the current date (see, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/5259921/2715819).  Specifically, try changing

```
worked_hours = (self.time_out - self.time_in).total_seconds() / 60 / 60
```

to:

```
datetime_in = datetime.combine(date.min, self.time_in)
datetime_out = datetime.combine(date.min, self.time_out)
worked_hours = (datetime_out - datetime_in).total_seconds() / 60 / 60
```

You'll also have to add `from datetime import datetime, date` at the top of your file.  You'll have to change the calculation of `overtime_hours` to use `datetime_out` instead of `self.time_out`, too.

Comment: this is my first proj on python and i recently started learning python online so i dont understand everything easily...It would be very kind of you if you could make changes in my code only @RishiG

Comment: @Dharmik better?

Comment: Its Perfect i understood what were you saying Thankyou so much

Comment: a liltle help here too Please [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49991630/9675047)