# Subtracting string and datetime.time repeatedly

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe which has a 'Time' column which has rows like `13:50:00`(it is of type string).Now I have a time of the format  and value `21:21:21`.I want to subtract the two.

Now I did abs(datetime.strptime(a, '%H:%M:%S').time()- recording_start_time))
which is still giving me the error

```
print(abs(datetime.strptime(a, '%H:%M:%S').time()- recording_start_time))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'
```

My code looks like-

```
 min_time_diff = abs(df3.loc[cond & cond2 ]['Time'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%H:%M:%S').time()- recording_start_time))
```

so I need a cleaner solution than the [subtract two times in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259882/subtract-two-times-in-python) provided here as it is searching through all the rows in 'Time' column and subtracting from a fixed value.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert to `datetime`, subtract from a `timedelta` and get back to `time`-only series by using `.dt` accessor

```
delta = datetime.timedelta(hours=21, minutes=21, seconds=21)
diff = pd.to_datetime(df.t, format="%H:%M:%S") - delta
>>> diff.dt.time
```

---

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'t':[time(2),time(8)]})

    t
0   02:00:00
1   08:00:00

d = pd.to_datetime(df.t, format="%H:%M:%S") - datetime.timedelta(minutes=1, seconds=1, hours=1)
d.dt.time

0    00:58:59
1    06:58:59
Name: t, dtype: object
```

Comment: my fixed variable is recording_start_time which has datatype datetime.time and the column ['Time'] has the format string...can you show how it is applicable in my case?

Comment: @ubuntu_noob the same code should work for your case too :) just create a `datetime.timedelta` from your `time` object, doing `datetime.timedelta(hours= recording_start_time.hour, minutes = recording_start_time.minutes, ...` ) etc

Comment: Could you explain how to convert the values in 'Time' column df.t?

Comment: I am saying my column ['Time'] has values in string format 15:30:00...and you are using df.t in your solution