# Unable to subtract a day from any specific date format

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, datetime

I'm trying to subtract a day from this date `06-30-2019` in order to make it `06-29-2019` but can't figure out any way to achive that.

I've tried with:

```
import datetime

date = "06-30-2019"
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date,'%m-%d-%Y').strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
print(date)
```

It surely gives me back the date I used above.

***How can I subtract a day from a date in the above format?***

Comment: Possible duplicate of [subtract two times in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259882/subtract-two-times-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to subtract a day from a date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441147/how-to-subtract-a-day-from-a-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
import datetime

date = "06/30/19" 
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%m/%d/%y") 
NewDate = date + datetime.timedelta(days=-1)

print(NewDate)  # 2019-06-29 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
date = "06-30-2019"
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date,'%m-%d-%Y').strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
```

Check type of date variable.

```
type(date)
Out[]: str
```

It is in string format. To perform subtraction operation you must convert it into date format first. You can use pd.to_datetime()

```
# Import packages
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta

# input date
date = "06-30-2019"
# Convert it into pd.to_datetime format
date = pd.to_datetime(date)
print(date)
# Substracting days
number_of_days = 1
new_date = date - timedelta(number_of_days)
print(new_date)
```

output:

```
2019-06-29 00:00:00
```

If you want to get rid of timestamp you can use:

```
str(new_date.date())
Out[]: '2019-06-29'
```

Comment: Is it possible to kick out timestamp from the result? Thanks.

Comment: I have revised my answer.

Answer (score 0):

use timedelta

```
import datetime
date = datetime.datetime.strptime("06/30/19" ,"%m/%d/%y")
print( date - datetime.timedelta(days=1))
```