# Convert DataFrame column type from string to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime-format, python-datetime

How can I convert a DataFrame column of strings (in ***dd/mm/yyyy*** format) to datetime dtype?

Answer (score 725, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df['col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col'])
```

It also offers a `dayfirst` argument for European times (but beware [this isn't strict](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3341)).

Here it is in action:

```
In [11]: pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['05/23/2005']))
Out[11]:
0   2005-05-23 00:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

You can pass a specific [format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

```
In [12]: pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['05/23/2005']), format="%m/%d/%Y")
Out[12]:
0   2005-05-23
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 75):

If your date column is a string of the format '2017-01-01'
you can use pandas astype to convert it to datetime.

```
df['date'] = df['date'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

or use datetime64[D] if you want Day precision and not nanoseconds

```
print(type(df['date'].iloc[0]))
```

yields

```
<class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp'>
```

the same as when you use pandas.to_datetime

You can try it with other formats then '%Y-%m-%d' but at least this works.

Comment: fyi when timezone is specified in the string it ignores it

Answer (score 57):

You can use the following if you want to specify tricky formats:

```
df['date_col'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['date_col'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

More details on `format` here:

- Python 2 https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior
- Python 3 https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Answer (score 23):

If you have a mixture of formats in your date, don't forget to set `infer_datetime_format=True` to make life easier.

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], infer_datetime_format=True)
```

Source: [pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas-to-datetime)

or if you want a customized approach:

```
def autoconvert_datetime(value):
    formats = ['%m/%d/%Y', '%m-%d-%y']  # formats to try
    result_format = '%d-%m-%Y'  # output format
    for dt_format in formats:
        try:
            dt_obj = datetime.strptime(value, dt_format)
            return dt_obj.strftime(result_format)
        except Exception as e:  # throws exception when format doesn't match
            pass
    return value  # let it be if it doesn't match

df['date'] = df['date'].apply(autoconvert_datetime)
```

Comment: A customized approach can be used without resorting to `.apply` which has no fast cache, and will struggle when converting a billion values. An alternative, but not a great one, is `col = pd.concat([pd.to_datetime(col, errors='coerce', format=f) for f in formats], axis='columns').bfill(axis='columns').iloc[:, 0]`

Comment: If you have a mixture of formats, you **should not use `infer_datetime_format=True`** as this assumes a single format. Just skip this argument. To understand why, try `pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['1/5/2015 8:08:00 AM', '1/4/2015 11:24:00 PM']), infer_datetime_format=True)` with and without `errors='coerce'`. See [this issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/25143).

Answer (score 8):

###### Multiple datetime columns

If you want to convert multiple string columns to datetime, then using `apply()` would be useful.

```py
df[['date1', 'date2']] = df[['date1', 'date2']].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

You can pass parameters to `to_datetime` as kwargs.

```py
df[['start_date', 'end_date']] = df[['start_date', 'end_date']].apply(pd.to_datetime, format="%m/%d/%Y")
```

Passing to `apply`, without specifying `axis`, still converts values vectorially *for each column*. `apply` is needed here because `pd.to_datetime` can only be called on a single column. If it has to be called on multiple columns, the options are either use an explicit `for-loop`, or pass it to `apply`. On the other hand, if you call `pd.to_datetime` using `apply` on a column (e.g. `df['date'].apply(pd.to_datetime))`, that would not be vectorized, and should be avoided.

---

###### Use `format=` to speed up

If the column contains a **time** component and you know the format of the datetime/time, then passing the format explicitly would significantly speed up the conversion. There's barely any difference if the column is only date, though. In my project, for a column with 5 millions rows, the difference was huge: ~2.5 min vs 6s.

It turns out explicitly specifying the format is about 25x faster. The following runtime plot shows that there's a huge gap in performance depending on whether you passed format or not.

[image: timings]

---

The code used to produce the plot:

```py
import perfplot
import random

mdYHM = range(1, 13), range(1, 29), range(2000, 2024), range(24), range(60)
perfplot.show(
    kernels=[lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x), lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')],
    labels=['pd.to_datetime(x)', "pd.to_datetime(x, format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')"],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(19)],
    setup=lambda n: pd.Series([f"{m}/{d}/{Y} {H}:{M}" 
                               for m,d,Y,H,M in zip(*[random.choices(e, k=n) for e in mdYHM])]),
    equality_check=pd.Series.equals,
    xlabel='len(df)'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:

- Change `'2022–12–31 00:00:00' to '2022–12–31 00:00:01'`
- Then run this code: `pandas.to_datetime(pandas.Series(['2022–12–31 00:00:01']))`
- Output: `2022–12–31 00:00:01`

Comment: *"Change '2022–12–31 00:00:00' to '2022–12–31 00:00:01'"* - What does that have to do with the question?

Answer (score -1):

```
print(df1.shape)
(638765, 95)

%timeit df1['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date']+" "+df1['HOUR'])
473 ms ± 8.33 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit df1['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date']+" "+df1['HOUR'], format='mixed')
688 ms ± 3.14 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit df1['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date']+" "+df1['HOUR'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
470 ms ± 7.31 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```