# Parsing nested JSON in python?

Tags: python, json, parsing, dataframe

I have a JSON file in following format

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5458c00ceb23024b941be4bb"
  },
  "gpstime": 0.046575,
  "gpslat": 12.94492917,
  "readingtime": {
    "$date": "2014-11-04T17:28:10.000+0000"
  },
  "gpslong": 77.56115458,
  "deviceid": "11119828",
  "time": "Tue Nov  4 12:01:16 2014",
  "location": [
    12.94492917,
    77.56115458
  ]
}
```

I used the following code to parse it but it is till missing out on date

```
import json
import csv
import pandas as pa

with open('readings.json', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

data = map(lambda x: x.rstrip(), data)
data_json_str = "[" + ','.join(data) + "]"
data_df = pa.read_json(data_json_str)
```

I get readingtime column as follows

```
readingtime  {u'$date': u'2014-11-04T17:27:50.000+0000'}
```

But is missing out on `%date` in reading time how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

The `time` field is correctly read, it correctly obtains its own column:

```
>>> print data_df.time
0    Tue Nov  4 12:01:16 2014
Name: time, dtype: object
```

Please note that neither `$date` nor `time` fields are *intepreted*, they are just loaded as strings.

Comment: how to convert time field to datetime format while parsing?  Also How to parse the readingtime field properly to get date&time?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134716/convert-dataframe-column-type-from-string-to-datetime