# Proper Schema for Spark (when loading data into Dataframe)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, schema, structure

I have following structure in RedShift after running describe on a table (all fields are Nullable):

```
a integer
b numeric(18)
c date
d char(3)
e smallint
f char(1)
g varchar(20)
h numeric(11,2)
```

All data is extracted to S3. Now want to load data into Spark Dataframe but need to create a proper schema for this table as well.

How would Spark schema look like for these fields?

Is this structure correct? (wondering specially about Numeric (11,2), Date, Char(1) fields)

```
val schema = StructType( 
    Array( 
        StructField("a", IntegerType, true), 
        StructField("b", IntegerType, true), 
        StructField("c", StringType, true),
        StructField("d", StringType, true),
        StructField("e", IntegerType, true),
        StructField("f", StringType, true),
        StructField("g", StringType, true),
        StructField("h", IntegerType, true)
    ) 
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use :

- `DoubleType` or `DecimalType` for float value (like `NUMERIC(11,2)`). Decimal is better in my opinion, as it operates on BigDecimals
- `LongType` for very big numbers - like `NUMERIC(18)`. Otherwise it will not be stored properly
- `DateType` for dates - it can be stored as a string, but if you can, you should choose more meaningful type

Comment: Thanks! Does the DateType need to follow specific format (or converted to specific format)? (e.g. MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS)

Comment: @Joe You can easily convert string in any format to Date: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40763796/convert-date-from-string-to-date-format-in-dataframes

Comment: At which moment we should use LongType instead of IntegerType? (e.g. when field in Database is defined as Numeric(5) or Numeric(10) or Numeric(15)...?)

Comment: Integer has maximum value of  2147483647. If you use higher numbers, then you should use LongType. `b` can have 18 digits, so it should be `LongType`, `h` also is too big, but also with fraction part - that's why I recommend DecimalType (or DoubleType if you use Doubles in code - Decimal is safier as it can holds much bigger numbers)

Comment: Thanks. I am getting this error when trying DecimalType (all other Types are OK):
<console>:84: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.types.DecimalType.type
 required: org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType
         StructField("aff_num",DecimalType, true)

Comment: @Joe Try `DecimalType(11,2)`