# converting dd-MMM-yy date format in Spark

Tags: scala, date, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark data frame (Scala API) which contains a column called `transfer date`, the dates are in `string` format and are in this format `24-JUL-17`.

I want to convert it to date string into timestamp. How can I do it?

Answer (score 5):

It can also be done with [`to_timestamp(date_col, expr)`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@to_timestamp(s:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,fmt:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.to_timestamp

val df = date.withColumn("ts", to_timestamp($"transfer date", "dd-MMM-yy"))
```

Now **ts** column in *df* is of `timestamp` type.

Comment: I have date column in my dataframe like ...01-01-2012 , 31-01-2012 , how to convert  like 01-Jan-2012 , 31-Jan-2012 format ?  How to filter the data between these two date???

Answer (score 4):

I found it :

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.unix_timestamp

val ts = unix_timestamp($"transfer date", "dd-MMM-yy").cast("timestamp")
dfs.withColumn("ts",ts).show()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40763796/convert-date-from-string-to-date-format-in-dataframes/55465096#55465096