# Convert String to date SparkSQL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I'm new to in Scala, I have dataframe where I'm trying one column of dataframe to date from string in other word like below

```
1)    yyyyMMddHHmmss(20150610120256) ->yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss(2015-06-10 12:02:56) 
2)    yyyyMMddHHmmss(20150611      ) ->yyyy-MM-dd(2015-06-11)
```

First case i'm able achieve successfully but problem with second case where time is miss due to of this i'm not bale to convert into date.More details you could get below.Any help will be appreciated.

```
df.printSchema
root
 |-- TYPE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CODE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SQ_CODE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- RE_TYPE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- VERY_ID: long (nullable = true)
 |-- IN_DATE: string (nullable = true)


df.show
Input  
+-----+-------+---------+---------+-------------------+-----------------+
| TYPE|   CODE|  SQ_CODE| RE_TYPE |            VERY_ID|  IN_DATE        |
+-----+-------+---------+---------+-------------------+-----------------+
|   F | 000544|  2017002|      OP |  95032015062763298| 20150610120256  |
|   F | 000544|  2017002|      LD |  95032015062763261| 20150611        |
|   F | 000544|  2017002|      AK |  95037854336743246| 20150611012356  |
+-----+-------+---------+--+------+-------------------+-----------------+

df=df.withColumn("IN_DATE",when(lit(length(regexp_replace(df("IN_DATE"),"\\s+",""))) === lit(8) ,
        to_date(from_unixtime(regexp_replace(df("IN_DATE"),"\\s+",""),"yyyyMMdd").cast("date")))
        .otherwise(unix_timestamp(df("IN_DATE"),"yyyyMMddHHmmss").cast("timestamp")))

Actual output
+-----+-------+---------+---------+-------------------+----------------------+
| TYPE|   CODE|  SQ_CODE| RE_TYPE |            VERY_ID|  IN_DATE             |
+-----+-------+---------+---------+-------------------+----------------------+
|   F | 000544|  2017002|      OP |  95032015062763298| 2015-06-10 12:02:56  |
|   F | 000544|  2017002|      LD |  95032015062763261| null                 |
|   F | 000544|  2017002|      AK |  95037854336743246| 2015-06-11 01:23:56  |
+-----+-------+---------+--+------+-------------------+----------------------+

df=df.withColumn("IN_DATE",when(lit(length(regexp_replace(df("IN_DATE"),"\\s+",""))) === lit(8) ,
        to_date(from_unixtime(regexp_replace(df("IN_DATE"),"\\s+",""),"yyyyMMdd").cast("timestamp")))
        .otherwise(unix_timestamp(df("IN_DATE"),"yyyyMMddHHmmss").cast("timestamp")))

Actual output
+-----+-------+---------+---------+-------------------+----------------------+
| TYPE|   CODE|  SQ_CODE| RE_TYPE |            VERY_ID|  IN_DATE             |
+-----+-------+---------+---------+-------------------+----------------------+
|   F | 000544|  2017002|      OP |  95032015062763298| 2015-06-10 12:02:56  |
|   F | 000544|  2017002|      LD |  95032015062763261| 2015-06-11 00:00:00  |
|   F | 000544|  2017002|      AK |  95037854336743246| 2015-06-11 01:23:56  |
+-----+-------+---------+--+------+-------------------+----------------------+


Expected output
+-----+-------+---------+---------+-------------------+----------------------+
| TYPE|   CODE|  SQ_CODE| RE_TYPE |            VERY_ID|  IN_DATE             |
+-----+-------+---------+---------+-------------------+----------------------+
|   F | 000544|  2017002|      OP |  95032015062763298| 2015-06-10 12:02:56  |
|   F | 000544|  2017002|      LD |  95032015062763261| 2015-06-11           |
|   F | 000544|  2017002|      AK |  95037854336743246| 2015-06-11 01:23:56  |
+-----+-------+---------+--+------+-------------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: That would be impossible as both dates datatype is different. one is TimestampType and the other is DateType and you can't really have two schemas for the same column.

Answer (score 2):

I'd

- Choose more precise data type - here `TimestampType`.
- `coalesce` with different formats.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq("20150610120256", "20150611").toDF("IN_DATE")

df.withColumn("IN_DATE", coalesce(
  to_timestamp($"IN_DATE", "yyyyMMddHHmmss"), 
  to_timestamp($"IN_DATE", "yyyyMMdd"))).show


+-------------------+
|            IN_DATE|
+-------------------+
|2015-06-10 12:02:56|
|2015-06-11 00:00:00|
+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several options to achieve a date parser.

1. Use the built in spark sql function `TODATE()`. [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40763796/convert-date-from-string-to-date-format-in-dataframes) of that implementation.
2. Create a user defined function where you can do different date parsing based on the input format you like, and return the string. Read more about UDF's [here](http://www.sparktutorials.net/using-sparksql-udfs-to-create-date-times-in-spark-1.5).

Answer (score 1):

`2015-06-11`  format is `spark.sql.types.DateType` and `2015-06-10 12:02:56` is `spark.sql.types.TimestampType`

You can't have two *dataType* on the same column. A *schema* should have only one *dataType* for each *columns*.

I would suggest you to create two new columns and have the format you desire in them as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{DateType, TimestampType}
df.withColumn("IN_DATE_DateOnly",from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(df("IN_DATE"),"yyyyMMdd")).cast(DateType))
  .withColumn("IN_DATE_DateAndTime",unix_timestamp(df("IN_DATE"),"yyyyMMddHHmmSS").cast(TimestampType))
```

this will give you `dataframe` as

```
+----+------+-------+-------+-----------------+--------------+----------------+---------------------+
|TYPE|CODE  |SQ_CODE|RE_TYPE|VERY_ID          |IN_DATE       |IN_DATE_DateOnly|IN_DATE_DateAndTime  |
+----+------+-------+-------+-----------------+--------------+----------------+---------------------+
|F   |000544|2017002|OP     |95032015062763298|20150610120256|null            |2015-06-10 12:02:00.0|
|F   |000544|2017002|LD     |95032015062763261|20150611      |2015-06-11      |null                 |
|F   |000544|2017002|AK     |95037854336743246|20150611012356|null            |2015-06-11 01:23:00.0|
+----+------+-------+-------+-----------------+--------------+----------------+---------------------+
```

You can see that the *dataType* is different

```
root
 |-- TYPE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CODE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SQ_CODE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- RE_TYPE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- VERY_ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- IN_DATE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- IN_DATE_DateOnly: date (nullable = true)
 |-- IN_DATE_DateAndTime: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try This query

```
df.withColumn("IN_DATE",when(lit(length(regexp_replace(df("IN_DATE"),"\\s+",""))) === lit(8) ,
to_date(from_unixtime(regexp_replace(df("IN_DATE"),"\\s+",""),"yyyyMMdd").cast(DateType)))
.otherwise(unix_timestamp(df("IN_DATE"),"yyyyMMddHHmmSS").cast(TimestampType)))
```

Comment: Why the `regexp_replace`? We have `trim` in spark sql.