# Spark 2.0 How to convert DF Date/timstamp column to another date format in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

For my learning , i have been using below sample dataset .

```
+-------------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------+
|             MyDate| Open| High|  Low|Close| Volume|
+-------------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------+
|2006-01-03 00:00:00|983.8|493.8|481.1|492.9|1537660|
|2006-01-04 00:00:00|979.6|491.0|483.5|483.8|1871020|
|2006-01-05 00:00:00|972.2|487.8|484.0|486.2|1143160|
|2006-01-06 00:00:00|977.8|489.0|482.0|486.2|1370250|
|2006-01-09 00:00:00|973.4|487.4|483.0|483.9|1680740|
+-------------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------+
```

I tried to change "MyDate" column values to different format like "YYYY-MON" and written like this..

```
citiDataDF.withColumn("New-Mydate",to_timestamp($"MyDate", "yyyy-MON")).show(5)
```

After executing the code, found that new column "New-Mydate". but i couldn't see the desired output format. can you please help

Comment: Check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40763796/convert-date-from-string-to-date-format-in-dataframes

Comment: I am using DF.. the above mentioned url is not helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `date_format` instead `to_timestamp`:

```
val citiDataDF = List("2006-01-03 00:00:00").toDF("MyDate")
citiDataDF.withColumn("New-Mydate",date_format($"New-Mydate", "yyyy-MMM")).show(5)
```

Result:

```
+-------------------+----------+
|             MyDate|New-Mydate|
+-------------------+----------+
|2006-01-03 00:00:00|  2006-Jan|
+-------------------+----------+
```

**Note:** Three "M" mean the month as string, if you want a month as Int, you must use only two "M"

Comment: Lopez : sorry there is no change in the output.

Comment: +-------------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------+-------------------+
|             MyDate| Open| High|  Low|Close| Volume|         New-Mydate|
+-------------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------+-------------------+
|2006-01-03 00:00:00|490.0|493.8|481.1|492.9|1537660|2006-01-03 00:00:00|

Comment: Lopez.. Great .. thanks ..it is working as expected