# Convert string to date using pyspark

Tags: string, date, pyspark, type-conversion

I have a pyspark dataframe with a string column in the format of YYYYMMDD and I am attempting to convert this into a date column (I should have a final date ISO 8061). The field is named deadline and is formatted as follows:

```
deadline
20190530
```

I tried the following solutions:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import unix_timestamp, col
from pyspark.sql.types import TimestampType
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_unixtime
from pyspark.sql.types import DateType

df.select(to_date(df.deadline).alias('dt')).show()

df.withColumn('new_date',to_date(unix_timestamp(df.deadline, 'YYYYMMDD').cast('timestamp'))).show()

orders_concat.select(unix_timestamp(orders_concat.deadline, 'YYYYMMDD')).show()

df.select(unix_timestamp(df.ts_string, 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss').cast(TimestampType()).alias("timestamp")).show()


df.select(unix_timestamp(df.deadline, 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss').cast(TimestampType()).alias("timestamp")).show()

df.select(to_date(cast(unix_timestamp('deadline', 'YYYYMMDD').alias('timestamp').show()

 ndf = df.withColumn('_1', df['deadline'].cast(DateType()))

 df2 = df.select('deadline', from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('deadline', 'YYYYMMDD')).alias('date'))
```

I always get null values.

Does anyone has suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert date from String to Date format in Dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40763796/convert-date-from-string-to-date-format-in-dataframes)

Comment: @Steven I tried the solution posted in that post but none worked. I will edit the code because I did not notice I posted the old version (in the new one I tried the correct data format)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with the right format `yyyyMMdd`, it works fine :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn('new_date',F.to_date(F.unix_timestamp(df.deadline, 'yyyyMMdd').cast('timestamp'))).show() 

    +--------+----------+                                                           
    |deadline|  new_date|
    +--------+----------+
    |20190530|2019-05-30|
    +--------+----------+
```