# Convert datetime to date on PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with two columns `"date" (dtype: string)` and `"modified" (dtype: bigint)` as shown below:

```
+-------------------------------------+-------------+
|                                 date|     modified|
+-------------------------------------+-------------+
|Mon, 18 Dec 2017 22:52:37 +0000 (UTC)|1513637587000|
|      Mon, 18 Dec 2017 22:52:23 +0000|1513637587000|
|      Mon, 18 Dec 2017 22:52:03 +0000|1513637587000|
|Mon, 18 Dec 2017 22:51:43 +0000 (UTC)|1513637527000|
|      Mon, 18 Dec 2017 22:51:31 +0000|1513637527000|
|      Mon, 18 Dec 2017 22:51:38 +0000|1513637527000|
|      Mon, 18 Dec 2017 22:51:09 +0000|1513637526000|
|      Mon, 18 Dec 2017 22:50:55 +0000|1513637466000|
|      Mon, 18 Dec 2017 22:50:35 +0000|1513637466000|
|      Mon, 18 Dec 2017 17:49:35 -0500|1513637407000|
+-------------------------------------+-------------+
```

How to extract `YYYY-mm-dd (2017-12-18)` from any of the two columns? I tried using `unix_timestamp`, and  `to_timestamp` but nothing worked. It gives `null` value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `from_unixtime` to cast the bigint unix timestamp into a timestamp type, and then cast to date type:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn('parsed_date', F.from_unixtime(F.col('modified')/1000).cast('date'))

df2.show()
+--------------------+-------------+-----------+
|                date|     modified|parsed_date|
+--------------------+-------------+-----------+
|Mon, 18 Dec 2017 ...|1513637587000| 2017-12-18|
|Mon, 18 Dec 2017 ...|1513637587000| 2017-12-18|
|Mon, 18 Dec 2017 ...|1513637587000| 2017-12-18|
|Mon, 18 Dec 2017 ...|1513637527000| 2017-12-18|
|Mon, 18 Dec 2017 ...|1513637527000| 2017-12-18|
|Mon, 18 Dec 2017 ...|1513637527000| 2017-12-18|
|Mon, 18 Dec 2017 ...|1513637526000| 2017-12-18|
|Mon, 18 Dec 2017 ...|1513637466000| 2017-12-18|
|Mon, 18 Dec 2017 ...|1513637466000| 2017-12-18|
|Mon, 18 Dec 2017 ...|1513637407000| 2017-12-18|
+--------------------+-------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Many questions have been posted here on how to convert strings to date in Spark ([Convert pyspark string to date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080748/convert-pyspark-string-to-date-format), [Convert date from String to Date format in Dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40763796/convert-date-from-string-to-date-format-in-dataframes)...).

You are getting null because the `modified` column is epoch time in **milliseconds**, you need to divide it by 1000 to get seconds before converting it into a timestamp:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = df.withColumn(
    "modified_as_date",
    F.to_timestamp(F.col("modified") / 1000).cast("date")
).withColumn(
    "date_as_date",
    F.to_date("date", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss")
)

df1.show(truncate=False)

#+-------------------------------------+-------------+----------------+------------+
#|date                                 |modified     |modified_as_date|date_as_date|
#+-------------------------------------+-------------+----------------+------------+
#|Mon, 18 Dec 2017 22:52:37 +0000 (UTC)|1513637587000|2017-12-18      |2017-12-18  |
#|Mon, 18 Dec 2017 22:52:23 +0000      |1513637587000|2017-12-18      |2017-12-18  |
#|Mon, 18 Dec 2017 22:52:03 +0000      |1513637587000|2017-12-18      |2017-12-18  |
#|Mon, 18 Dec 2017 22:51:43 +0000 (UTC)|1513637527000|2017-12-18      |2017-12-18  |
#|Mon, 18 Dec 2017 22:51:31 +0000      |1513637527000|2017-12-18      |2017-12-18  |
#|Mon, 18 Dec 2017 22:51:38 +0000      |1513637527000|2017-12-18      |2017-12-18  |
#|Mon, 18 Dec 2017 22:51:09 +0000      |1513637526000|2017-12-18      |2017-12-18  |
#|Mon, 18 Dec 2017 22:50:55 +0000      |1513637466000|2017-12-18      |2017-12-18  |
#|Mon, 18 Dec 2017 22:50:35 +0000      |1513637466000|2017-12-18      |2017-12-18  |
#|Mon, 18 Dec 2017 17:49:35 -0500      |1513637407000|2017-12-18      |2017-12-18  |
#+-------------------------------------+-------------+----------------+------------+
```