# String to date type in spark datafrme

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I need to create a new column in a spark dataframe that contains a date type.
Now it is a string: "Mon Jan 09 2021" but it needs to be as follows: YYYY-MM-DD.

I tried several ways but they all failed. How do you need to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert date from String to Date format in Dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40763796/convert-date-from-string-to-date-format-in-dataframes)

Answer (score 0):

January 9, 2021 is a Saturday, so first you should check that it's your Dataframe contains valid data, otherwise this won't work. Assuming the column with the string data is called `date_string`, and we change the string data to `"Sat Jan 09 2021", we can use

```
SELECT
    TO_DATE(date_string, "EEE MM dd yyyy") AS date
```

to cast the data into date. By default, it should display in the format you want, but in case it doesn't, you can use [`date_format`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html#date_format) to specify the format you need. The specification for the format string to pass in is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html). This specification is also used in the `to_date()` function I used above.