# how to convert date of format string to timestamp in spark?

Tags: string, apache-spark, date, timestamp

```
%scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, to_date}

Seq(("20110813"),("20090724")).toDF("Date").select(
col("Date"),
to_date(col("Date"),"yyyy-mm-dd").as("to_date")
).show()

+--------+-------+
|    Date|to_date|
+--------+-------+
|20110813|   null|
|20090724|   null|
+--------+-------+
+--------+----------+
|    Date|   to_date|
+--------+----------+
|20110813|2011-01-13|
|20090724|2009-01-24|
+--------+----------+
Seq(("20110813"),("20090724")).toDF("Date").select(
col("Date"),
to_date(col("Date"),"yyyymmdd").as("to_date")
).show()
```

I am trying to convert a string to timestamp, but I am getting always null/default values returned to the date value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert date from String to Date format in Dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40763796/convert-date-from-string-to-date-format-in-dataframes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't given value for the new column to convert. you should use withColumn to add the new date column and tell him to use Date column values.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, to_date}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
    
val df = Seq((20110813),(20090724)).toDF("Date")
val newDf = df.withColumn("to_date", to_date(col("Date").cast(TimestampType), "yyyy-MM-dd"))
newDf.show()
```

Comment: Check your code (it's wrong), don't skip imports, and add the execution results.