# saving datetime with milliseconds and time zone - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, strptime

I can't figure out the correct second argument of `strptime` for the following date format

```
a = datetime.strptime('2017-03-09 14:00:00.000000+0000', '%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f+%z')
```

The error I get is:

```
ValueError: time data '2017-03-09 14:00:00.000000+0000' does not match format '%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f+%z'
```

Could anyone help me out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct format string is:

```
%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z
```

You can figure this out more easily next time by using `strftime()` to write a datetime using a given format.  For example, your original:

```
datetime.datetime.now().astimezone(tz=None).strftime('%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f+%z')
```

gives:

```
17-03-13 22:53:50.010314++0800
```

And from there it is fairly easy to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 4):

This is how it goes:

```
import datetime

output_date = datetime.datetime.now(tz = datetime.datetime.now().astimezone().tzinfo).isoformat(timespec='milliseconds')

print(output_date)
```

Gives:

```
"2021-04-20T16:56:29.800+02:00"
```

Which is in ISO 8601 yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX format.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are fine, it is just that I guess that the question about one example case arose from a full column of a dataframe that needs to be converted to datetime.

Just for those who have a dataframe instead and need to reformat the whole column like me:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['MY_STR_TIMESTAMP_COLUMN_NAME'])
```

Taken from [Convert DataFrame column type from string to datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134716/convert-dataframe-column-type-from-string-to-datetime).

If you are lazy and do not mind the overhead of pandas, then you could do this even for just one entry.