# How to plot (in matplotlib) python pandas dataframe containing two columns, one of timeseries and one of value?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph, data-analysis

My Python Pandas Dataframe Looks like this:

[image]

I want to plot dates on X-axis and values on Y-axis
I am able to get it one at a time. Either X axis or Y axis. I want them together in one graph.

I have tried something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame, Panel
from mysql.connector import MySQLConnection, Error
from python_mysql_dbconfig import read_db_config
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dbconfig = read_db_config()
conn = MySQLConnection(**dbconfig)
cur = conn.cursor()

df_mysql = pd.read_sql('SELECT PO_Date,PO_Total FROM purchase_order',con=conn)

print df_mysql
po_dates =  df_mysql.ix[:,0]
po_total = df_mysql.ix[:,1]

X = Series( po_total,index=po_dates)
X.plot()
plt.show()

conn.close()
```

How to plot these 2 columns together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it can be even easier and native:

```
df_mysql.columns = ['po_date','po_total']
df_mysql.plot('po_date','po_total')
```

the first line (column name assigning) can be done as an argument during the loading itself -`pd.read_sql(<args>, columns = ['po_date','po_total'] )`

Comment: you can just use the plot function twice in two rows. ``matplotlib`` is holding the existing figure by default and letting you present few trendlines together.


    ``df_mysql.columns = ['po_date','po_total1',po_total2']``

    ``df_mysql.plot('po_date','po_total1')``

    ``df_mysql.plot('po_date','po_total2')``

Answer (score 0):

```
  X = Series( po_total.values,index=po_dates)
  X.plot()
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly. Was missing that small thing.

Comment: I had marked it earlier, but it seems Dimgold's answer is more accurate. I wish I could mark both. :P

Comment: Just checked that. I'd agree with you on that.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to convert the date data to [datetime format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134716/convert-dataframe-column-type-from-string-to-datetime):

Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
# To obtain stock data online, import pandas.io.data namespace, alias as web
from pandas_datareader import data, wb

# datetime for the dates
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# start end end dates
start = datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 9)

# read from Google finance and display the first five rows
ibm = data.DataReader("IBM", 'google', start, end)
ibm.head()

# Create a figure and add an axes in which to plot the data
fig1 = plt.figure(figsize = (5, 3))
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(1,1,1)

# Define the variables you wish to plot
# The web data reader indexes the dataframe by date; get_level_values
# retrieves those dates from the index
x = ibm.index.get_level_values(0)
y = ibm.Close

ax1.plot(x, y, color = '0.5')

plt.show()
```

Comment: My data is already in datetime format. "datetime.date" to be specific. Thanks anyway. Linda's solution was the one I was looking for,

Comment: Glad your problem is solved.  Do check out the object-oriented mode of using Matplotlib, though.