# Convert column to timestamp - Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a Pandas DataFrame that has date values stored in 2 columns in the below format:

```
col1: 04-APR-2018 11:04:29
col2: 2018040415203
```

How could I convert this to a time stamp. Dtype of both of these columns is `object`.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

For the first format you can simply pass to_datetime, for the latter you need to explicitly describe the date format ([see the table of available directives in the python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)):

```
In [21]: df
Out[21]:
                   col1           col2
0  04-APR-2018 11:04:29  2018040415203

In [22]: pd.to_datetime(df.col1)
Out[22]:
0   2018-04-04 11:04:29
Name: col1, dtype: datetime64[ns]

In [23]: pd.to_datetime(df.col2, format="%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
Out[23]:
0   2018-04-04 15:20:03
Name: col2, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: What I don't understand, is that this convert's it to `np.datetime64`, whereas I need to do some `pd.Timedelta` math which only works with `pd.Timestamp`. I can't find anywhere how to convert the column to `pd.Timestamp`... think I'll open a new Q

Comment: @j7skov It produces `pd.Timestamp`s. If you're interested, I added an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75432626/19123103) that kind of shows other ways to convert each element into `pd.Timestamp` objects but ultimately all are the same. Cheers.

Answer (score 20):

You can try these as well.
Try passing **infer_datetime_format = True** while reading the file.

if the above method fails try the following

```
df2 = pd.to_datetime(df.col1)
```

or

```
df2 = pd.to_datetime(df['col1'])
df2
```

Note the above methods will only convert the str to datetime format and return them in df2. In short df2 will have only the datetime format of str without a column name for it. If you want to retain other columns of the dataframe and want to give a header to the    converted column you can try the following

```
df['col1_converetd'] = pd.to_datetime(df.col1)
```

or

```
df['col1_converetd'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col1'])
```

This is comforatble if you dont want to create a dataframe or want to refer the converted column in future together with other attributes of the dataframe.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways to convert column values into timestamps, some more efficient than others. N.B. Passing `format=` to `to_datetime` makes the conversion much, much faster (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75253473/19123103)). You can find all possible combination of datetime formats at https://strftime.org/.

```py
from datetime import datetime
x = pd.to_datetime(df['col1'], format='%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S')
y = df['col1'].apply(pd.Timestamp)
z = df['col1'].apply(datetime.strptime, args=('%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S',))
```

but ultimately, all produce the same object (`x.equals(y) and x.equals(z)` returns `True`) that looks like:

```
0   2018-04-04 11:04:29
Name: col1, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

If we check the individual values, they are the same (`x[0] == y[0] == z[0]` returns `True`) that looks like

```
Timestamp('2018-04-04 11:04:29')
```

If we look at the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/_libs/tslibs/timestamps.pyx), `pd.Timestamp` is a subclass of `datetime.datetime`, so all are ultimately tied by `datetime.datetime`.