# Missing xticks on chart for matplotlib on Python 3

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am following this section, I realize this code was made using Python 2 but they have xticks showing on the `'Start Date'` axis and I do not. My chart only shows `Start Date` and no dates are provided.

[image: graph]
    # Set as_index=False to keep the 0,1,2,... index. Then we'll take the mean of the polls on that day.
    poll_df = poll_df.groupby(['Start Date'],as_index=False).mean()

```
# Let's go ahead and see what this looks like
poll_df.head()
Start Date  Number of Observations  Obama   Romney  Undecided   Difference
0   2009-03-13  1403    44  44  12  0.00
1   2009-04-17  686 50  39  11  0.11
2   2009-05-14  1000    53  35  12  0.18
3   2009-06-12  638 48  40  12  0.08
4   2009-07-15  577 49  40  11  0.09
Great! Now plotting the Differencce versus time should be straight forward.

# Plotting the difference in polls between Obama and Romney
fig = poll_df.plot('Start Date','Difference',figsize=(12,4),marker='o',linestyle='-',color='purple')
```

https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/jmportilla/Udemy-notes/blob/master/Data%20Project%20-%20Election%20Analysis.ipynb

Comment: You may need to download the graph to see it properly as it has no background.

Comment: I think you forgot to convert the start date column to actual dates.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks for your reply but how would I do that in the context of this question and why didn't they have to convert the date in the example? Thanks.

Comment: [How](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134716/convert-dataframe-column-type-from-string-to-datetime). As to why, I have no idea, possibly some older versions did behave differently.

Comment: Thanks for your reply again, I have tried your suggestion but now it breaks the function of the graph below it. It even affects this persons project of the same type. https://www.kaggle.com/kadser/analysis-of-romney-vs-obama/notebook while the dates come back it breaks that graph completely after changing the 'Start Date' to datetime64[ns], I am using Jupyter Notebook btw.

Comment: herepoll_df.plot('Start Date','Difference', figsize=(12,4), marker='o', linestyle='-',color='purple', xlim=(329,356))
#debate oct 3rd 329 corresponds to October 1st
plt.axvline(x=329+2,linewidth=4,color='blue')
#debate oct 11th
plt.axvline(x=329+10,linewidth=4,color='blue')
#debate oct 22nd
plt.axvline(x=329+21,linewidth=4,color='blue')

Comment: I suppose that other notebook is then also produced by the older pandas version.

Comment: I have pandas 0.23.4 and numpy 1.15.4. Python 3. The notebook was also created by Python 3 but the original I found was using Python 2. Do you have a fix?

Comment: The important bit is that the column needs to be datetimes (i.e. of type `datetime64`). I do not know what breaks when you do that, but best do not set the `xlim` at all. Then you can filter the data itself into the range you want to plot.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks, how do I do that?