# Speed up Pandas - speed up changing unix timestamp to date in whole column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with a column which has a time represented as a unix timestamp. I would like to parse the whole column to represent time as datetime (year-month-day-hours-minute-second). I did it using the foor loop but it takes a long time for large `DataFrame`. Can I speed this up or maybe is there some built-in Pandas function which I can use instead?

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
            df.loc[idx, "time"] = pd.to_datetime(row['time'], unit='s')
```

Comment: Just don't loop, do it with `df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='s')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert DataFrame column type from string to datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134716/convert-dataframe-column-type-from-string-to-datetime)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by accessing the column directly and specifying the format:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')
```

Answer (score 1):

d_kennetz's answer is the right one, but it is also useful to know that `df.at()` should perform a lot better for you than `df.loc()` in this case. I'd be willing to bet that `df.at()` would be at least one thousand times faster than `df.loc()`:

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
            df.at[idx, "time"] = pd.to_datetime(row['time'], unit='s')
```

This isn't the solution I'd recommend in this case, but this information may be useful to you or someone else later on.