# Jupyter date function

Tags: python, jupyter

I am trying to convert a column of dates in the format 4-Mar-20 into a integer or numeric value in order to fit as vector in machine learning model.

I keep getting error message:

> ValueError: time data 'Date' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y' (match)

Comment: You input doesn't match the format you specified. Refer https://strftime.org/

Comment: Try `print(datetime.strptime('4-Mar-20', '%d-%b-%y'))`

Answer (score 1):

You should use the format like `%d-%b-%y`

```py
from datetime import datetime

date1 = datetime.strptime('4-Mar-20', '%d-%b-%y')

print(date1) #2020-02-04 00:00:00
```

Comment: Sorry if this may be a stupid question but how would I apply that to an entire 'Date' Column

Comment: @MunirYousef Refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17134716/3091398). This `df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'])` or `df['Dates'] = df['Dates'].map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d-%b-%y'))` will do.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas library has inbuilt datetime convertor which does a very good job 
Here is a code snippet:

Import pandas as pd

pd.to_datetime("4-Mar-20")

This will convert without any issues