# Python How to convert the date time?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

Hello every one i am trying to convert date. I have this '  January 7, 2018'  type of date and i am trying  to change the date format in 01-07-2018 or 07-01-2018 i am trying to covert the date. but not converted.

```
from datetime import datetime
df3 = df2.copy()
df3["Last Updated"] = [datetime.strptime(i, '%B %d, %Y') for i in df3["Last Updated"]]
```

i am trying this way to convert the date but not successful if you know the proper way or any mistake in my code so inform me or  help me to solve the error.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert DataFrame column type from string to datetime, dd/mm/yyyy format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134716/convert-dataframe-column-type-from-string-to-datetime-dd-mm-yyyy-format)

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the column to datetime first

```
df3['Last Updated'] = pd.to_datetime(df3['Last Updated'])
df3["Last Updated"] = [datetime.strptime(i, '%B %d, %Y') for i in df3["Last Updated"]]
```

Comment: i am trying your suggesstion .give me error as "day is out of range for month"

Comment: your second line makes no sense at all - the first one should simply be `df3['Last Updated'] = pd.to_datetime(df3['Last Updated'], format='%B %d, %Y')`

Comment: Yes this is fine, it can be done in a single line. I had added just to make it simple and not confuse with the existing code. It's easy to debug that way.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried replicating the dataset below:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

data = pd.DataFrame({'App':['a','b'],'Category':['Art&Design','Art&Design'],'Date':['January 7, 2018', 'January 8, 2018']})
data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date']).dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
print(data)
```

Comment: but this method how we can use with dataframe column?

Comment: Why dont you give me the first 5 rows of your dataset and let me work on it? :)

Comment: sir i edit my post and add the image plz check it sir and help me

Comment: data['Last Updated'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Last Updated']).dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')