# How can i generate a range of dates from a string and obtain another list of string in python?

Tags: python, pandas, string, datetime, time

I have a single date:

```
Data_raw = "08/09/20 21:05"
```

How can i generate a list of dates (type=str) included in an interval of +-40 minutes? Please note that I have already tried the following code:

```
    Data = datetime.strptime(Data_raw,'%d/%m/%y %H:%M')
    a = Data
    c = a + timedelta(minutes=40)
    b = a - timedelta(minutes=40)
    Upper_limit = str(pd.date_range(start=Data, end=c, periods=41))
    Lower_limit = str(pd.date_range(start=Data, end=b, periods=41))
```

Unfortunately when I try to filter a DataFrame with `Upper_limit` and `Lower_limit` no result is shown.
On the other hand, if the filter is applied with the string (`Data_raw`) the DataFrame is succesfully filtered.

Thanks

Comment: What is "Data"?

Comment: also, what is your expected range of timestamps?  '2020-08-09 21:05:00' - 40 min to '2020-08-09 21:05:00' + 40 min? with minute frequency?

Comment: @tnknepp my bad, I added another missing line

Comment: @MrFuppes exactly

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Ok.  How are do you "filter a DataFrame with Upper_limit and Lower_limit"?

Comment: @DirtyBit 80 dates separated by 1 minute each

Comment: @tnknepp df_new = df.loc[df['DATIME'] == Upper_limit]
df_new_2 = df_new.loc[df_new['DATIME'] == Lower_limit]

Comment: Ok.  What is in the "DATIME" column of your dataframe?  Are these datetime values, or strings?

Comment: @tnknepp strings of dates, like Data_raw

Comment: it might be appropriate to convert `df['DATIME']` [to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

Comment: @Shold And there's your problem.  You are comparing different types.  Convert DATIME to datetime values and you are set.

Comment: @MrFuppes It is more than appropriate, it is necessary.

Comment: @tnknepp: technically, string comparison *should* work (if you cast the datetimeindex to string correctly...) but I'd recommend using datetime.

Comment: @MrFuppes Sure.  My point is you cannot compare a datetime to a string without converting one or the other.  I worded that poorly.

Comment: @tnknepp  oh i see so you suggest this way around, i really don't like to work with datetime sometimes it's very frustrating Or maybe I'm just a nub

Comment: @MrFuppes above

Comment: How can i convert a DatFrame column into datetime? to_datetime works fine?

Comment: @Shold There is probably something built into pandas that does this, but I normally use a list comprehension for this.  e.g. df.DATIME = [dt.datetime.strptime(r, "%m/%d/%y %H:%M") for r in df.DATIME].  If you want to keep DATIME as strings you can always create a new column for the datetime values.

Comment: make sure to use the pandas built-in, `pandas.to_datetime`, see my comment above. You can find plenty of resources on this, also [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134716/convert-dataframe-column-type-from-string-to-datetime-dd-mm-yyyy-format).

Comment: @MrFuppes finally it's working, is there anyway to give you and tnknepp points? Thanks

Comment: @tnknepp as above