# datetime confusing when pd.DataFrame to SQL Server INSERT

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas, datetime

pd.DataFrame has Date column (has datetime data type) with style such as:
`%dd.%mm.%yyyy #for example 03.08.2020`
but after INSERT to SQL Server
`df.to_sql(con_param)`
result in RDB looks like 08.03.2020 instead 03.08.2020.
Problem is not linear, cause for example 31.07.2020 looks like 31.07.2020.
Local of datebase is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.
What is wrong?
**UPD** to sql block fyi

```
correct_df = pd.read_csv(path)
correct_df = correct_df.astype({
                           'Req_Date': 'datetime64', 'Date': 'datetime64'})
                           
 correct_df.to_sql(con=conn, name='table', schema='schema', if_exists='append', index=False)
```

Comment: Dates have no style or format, they are binary values. Formats apply **only** if dates get converted to strings or vice versa. Your code is converting dates to strings somewhere - or there's no problem at all and your client tool displays dates in your locale - German? Russian?

Comment: None of what you actually state here actually makes a lot of sense. Date and time data types (in SQL Server) don't have *any* formats; they are stored as binary values. If you are inserting a date and time value as a string (that isn't unambiguous) and then getting a different value and/or format in the **presentation layer** that has nothing to do SQL Server. The problem is the ambiguous format used to insert the data, and the format choice in the presentation layer.

Comment: What tool did you use to check the dates? Why do you assume there's a problem to begin with? Have you tried using SSMS on Windows or Azure Data Studio, or any other database management tool to query the data?

Comment: When inserting date(time)s, ideally use a date and time data type from the application layer to the SQL. If not, then use an unambiguous string format; there are only 2 in SQL Server regardless of data type and language: `yyyyMMdd` and `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn`. As for the format displayed when you retrieve the data, that is entirely up to the presentation layer, so you would need to look at the application settings/code.

Comment: Python and Pandas have date types, and again, those have no format or style. Are you sure Pandas contains dates?  Perhaps it contains strings instead?

Comment: Thanks for info. @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, I sure, that all cells in  pd.DateFrime['Date'] have datetime64 data type. I check it and I cast it again before to_sql

Comment: You shouldn't have to cast anything. `df.to_sql` should be able to write dates as dates, not strings, unless there's a bug. Please post code that reproduces the problem

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes. I set in on ```pd.DataFrame``` level. So if cell can't to datetime, console throws error.

Comment: I think problem can be in collation diffrience between server and client

Comment: Dates aren't strings, they have no collation or codepage. They are binary values. You still haven't posted something that demonstrates the problem. How are you sure the incorrect conversion wasn't caused by `astype` parsing the file using a different date format than the one used in the CSV file?

Comment: You should probably use [pd.to_datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134716/convert-dataframe-column-type-from-string-to-datetime-dd-mm-yyyy-format) with a specific format when parsing the CSV's date fields

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert DataFrame column type from string to datetime, dd/mm/yyyy format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134716/convert-dataframe-column-type-from-string-to-datetime-dd-mm-yyyy-format)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos no. Cause my DataFrame['Date'] cells are datetime64. I check it by pd.to_datetime() too.

Comment: Are you sure? Are you 100% sure your user locale matches the format of the date strings in the CSV file? Have you tried `to_datetime` with an explicit format? You haven't posted any sample data yet, so a format mismatch is the most likely explanation. What do the dates in the CSV file look like?

Comment: `Cause my DataFrame['Date'] cells are datetime64` that doesn't mean much if the *wrong* format was used for parsing

Comment: ok. U say, that problem with locale matches between csv and pandas datetime, yes? visually it is looks eqally (03.08.2020 in csv and 03.08.2020 in pandas). So how I can check my user locale format of the date strings in the CSV file?

Answer (score 1):

So, thanks to Panagiotis Kanavos messages.
If you face with a problem like that, you have to set format of the date string of csv in your DateFrime.
For example

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d.%m.%Y') #format=f'{your_date_style}'
```

It can works. It works for me.