# Filtering based on two date columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to filter out all rows that hold wage data that were earned before the end date of a training. So basically I only want wages with a wage period greater than or equal to the end date. When I run the python similar to below it is removing too many fields. I'm confused why this isn't working

```
df = df[df['wage period']>= df['end date']]
```

| participant | end date | wage period | wage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | 1/1/2021 | 10/1/2020 | $100 |
| Bob | 1/1/2020 | 7/1/2020 | $150 |
| Jess | 10/1/2020 | 4/1/2020 | $100 |
| Bob | 1/1/2020 | 1/1/2020 | $200 |
| Bob | 1/1/2020 | 10/1/2019 | $120 |

Comment: Convert your date columns to actual datetime type with `pd.to_datetime`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134716/convert-dataframe-column-type-from-string-to-datetime-dd-mm-yyyy-format) question.

Comment: I had it as a period type because the data was quarterly. I did convert it to datetime though. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

May be you should convert the date (eg. '10/1/2020') to datetime, or change the format of the date if the type is String (eg. '2020/10/1').

Try this:

```
df['wage period'] = pd.to_datetime(df['wage period'], format='%m/%d/%Y')
df['end date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end date'], format='%m/%d/%Y')
df = df.loc[df['wage period'] >= df['end date'], :]
```