# Sum values of a column (Revenue) based on: the values of another column (Date) AND the value of another column (UserId) in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two tables/dataframes: **users** and **activity**.

In **users** I have the following columns: *UserId*, *Country*, *DOB*, *Gender*, *RegDate*, *WeekAfterRegDate*

where:

*UserId*: the Id of each user (only appears once in this table), there only one row for each UserId in this dataframe/table --> It is also the key column that links both tables/dataframes

*DOB*: date of birth

*RegDate*: Registration date of the user

*WeekAfterRegDate*: The date after 7 days since registration

In **activity** I have the following columns: *UserId*, *Date*, *Revenue*

where:

*UserId*: the same column as in the **users**, but it can appear in more than one row here as there dare different revenues

I need to calculate the average revenue generated per user in the first week

And I have been given these clues, which might be useful:

1. Merge the 2 datasets
2. Calculate the days since registration for each user and date in the activity table
3. Consider ALL REVENUE (not just the one generated by each user) generated in the first 7 days after registration for each user

In summary what I need to do is make a loop that sums *Renevue* between two *Dates* for each *UserId*. The period between the two dates is *RegDate* and *WeekAfterRegDate*.

I have been trying different methods, like groupby, etc, but I am a bit lost.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your date column is actually in datetime, since you won't be able to compare strings in order to filter out only those instances within the first week. See here for [converting strings into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134716/convert-dataframe-column-type-from-string-to-datetime-dd-mm-yyyy-format).

Merge both tables:

```
df_merged = pd.merge(activity,users,on='UserID')
```

You get the activity table including the respective dates in each row.

Filter the merged list:

```
df_merged = df_merged.loc[df_merged['Date'] >= df_merged['RegDate']] # lower bound
df_merged = df_merged.loc[df_merged['Date'] < df_merged['WeekAfterRegDate']] # upper bound
```

The table now contains only the relevant rows.

Now group by user and sum the revenue:

```
df_revenue = df_merged.groupby('UserID')['Revenue'].sum()
```

Comment: Okay, thank you. That was very helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

here's what i'd do:
first, make a list of the users from the first dataframe

```
user_list = first_df.UserId.unique().tolist()
```

then iterate over this list and over the second database something like this:

```
revenue_total = 0
for i in range(len(user_list)):
    for x in range(len(second_df):
        if second_df['userid'][x] == user_list[i] and second_df['Date'][x] <= first_df['WeekAfterRegDate'][i]:
            revenue_total = revenue_total + second_df['Revenue'][x]
```

then just simply divide the total revenue with the total users

```
 total_revenue /len(user_list)
```