# Hi, I am trying to use the resample function in pandas but when I use it i get this error: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python, pandas

Im want to organice some columns by weeks but it throws this error:
<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
an example of the dataframe is:

id----   date ------      count

1 2019-04-26    4

2 2019-04-26    3

3 2019-04-26    2

the code i used is ep27=ep27.resample("W").sum() where ep27 is the dataframe

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

For what you have provided, it looks like Pandas is giving you a `TypeError`, indicating that Pandas received a incompatible data types for the comparison operation `<`. Trying to use a less than operation on a string and an integer can produce the same error:

```py
>>> '2' < 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

The [`.dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html) method shows the data types for each column in your `DataFrame`. If your `date` column is listed as `object` this means it is a string and not a date. If so, you can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134716/convert-dataframe-column-type-from-string-to-datetime) on how to convert a string to a date. (When reading input from `.csv` files I often forget to apply the `parse_date=` keyword of `pd.read_csv`).

Here's a functional example of `.resample()`. The [docs for resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#resampling) do not state it clearly that I can tell, but one tricky aspect is that the date values must be in the **index**, which you can accomplish using [`.set_index('date')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html).

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create dataframe with on value per day
days = pd.date_range(start='2022-01-01', end='2022-01-31', freq='D')
counts = np.arange(days.shape[0])

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'date': days, 'count':counts})

# resample to sum over each week
df.set_index('date').resample('W').sum()
```

Comment: You could use `on="date"` to `.resample` along column `date`. (And you don't need `np.arange()` to create the `counts` column, a simple `range()` is enough.)

Comment: While your expanation seems sensible, I can't reproduce the exact `TypeError` from the question with the given example. I get `TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, ...` - which makes sense?