# Find Time difference Created Vs Resolved in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I have a data frame with 3 columns
Column 1 - Created
Column 2 - Resolved
Column 3 - Issue Type

I'm trying to figure out how much time has passed between Resolved and Created (days, hours, minutes, and seconds). When I try to do the same, I always receive the error below. Could someone please assist in cleaning these data and resolving them?

Sample data in dataframe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hjfA.png)

Error:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py in _na_arithmetic_op(left, right, op, is_cmp)
162     try:
--> 163         result = func(left, right)
164     except TypeError:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expressions.py in evaluate(op, a, b, use_numexpr)
238             # error: "None" not callable
--> 239             return _evaluate(op, op_str, a, b)  # type: ignore[misc]
240     return _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expressions.py in _evaluate_numexpr(op, op_str, a, b)
127     if result is None:
--> 128         result = _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b)
129

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expressions.py in _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b)
68         _store_test_result(False)
---> 69     return op(a, b)
70

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/k8/_5616sh16zs5g_n08g2sxk640000gp/T/ipykernel_13729/2306751620.py in 
----> 1 Time = jiraDump['Resolved'] - jiraDump['Created']

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/common.py in new_method(self, other)
68         other = item_from_zerodim(other)
69
---> 70         return method(self, other)
71
72     return new_method

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/arraylike.py in **sub**(self, other)
106     @unpack_zerodim_and_defer("**sub**")
107     def **sub**(self, other):
--> 108         return self._arith_method(other, operator.sub)
109
110     @unpack_zerodim_and_defer("**rsub**")

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in _arith_method(self, other, op)
5637     def _arith_method(self, other, op):
5638         self, other = ops.align_method_SERIES(self, other)
-> 5639         return base.IndexOpsMixin._arith_method(self, other, op)
5640
5641

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py in _arith_method(self, other, op)
1293
1294         with np.errstate(all="ignore"):
-> 1295             result = ops.arithmetic_op(lvalues, rvalues, op)
1296
1297         return self._construct_result(result, name=res_name)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py in arithmetic_op(left, right, op)
220         _bool_arith_check(op, left, right)
221
--> 222         res_values = _na_arithmetic_op(left, right, op)
223
224     return res_values

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py in _na_arithmetic_op(left, right, op, is_cmp)
168             # Don't do this for comparisons, as that will handle complex numbers
169             #  incorrectly, see GH#32047
--> 170             result = _masked_arith_op(left, right, op)
171         else:
172             raise

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py in _masked_arith_op(x, y, op)
106         # See GH#5284, GH#5035, GH#19448 for historical reference
107         if mask.any():
--> 108             result[mask] = op(xrav[mask], yrav[mask])
109
110     else:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: Can you paste your actual code?

Comment: `jiraDump = pd.read_csv('MongoDB Jira.csv', encoding='latin-1')`
`Time = jiraDump['Resolved'] - jiraDump['Created']`

Comment: The problem is that both columns are of type `str`. What you have to do is to convert both of them to `pd.to_datetime` before operating with them. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134716/convert-dataframe-column-type-from-string-to-datetime)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `parse` function from `parser` module in `dateutil` library. Once the datetime strings are parsed to datetime objects, you can get differnce

```py
import pandas as pd
from dateutil.parser import parse

data = {'issue_type': ['Deployment', 'Access'],
        'Created': ['Oct 07 2022 10:08:17 AM UTC', 'Sep 12 2022 06:08:24 AM UTC'],
        'Resolved': ['Oct 07 2022 04:56:25 PM UTC', 'Sep 12 2022 04:29:30 PM UTC']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

[image]

```py
df['Created'] = df['Created'].apply(parse)
df['Resolved'] = df['Resolved'].apply(parse)
print(df)
```

[image]

```py
df['delta'] = df['Resolved'] - df['Created']
df
```

[image]