# Input time twice as a string and calculate the difference

Tags: python

I am trying to take in a string for the time, for example `"10:20"`, then take in a second string,  for example `"10:25"`, and calculate the difference.

I am finding the `time` functions in Python difficult to understand.

Any pointers would be gratefully received.

Comment: Have a look at `datetime`, specifically [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Comment: Difficult to answer when we don't know what you find difficult to understand

Comment: Hope you will find the answer here at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096953/difference-between-two-time-intervals-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module . this is elegant **Pythonic** way !

```
from datetime import datetime
s1 = '10:20'
s2 = '11:25' 
tformat = '%H:%M' # specify the format of your time string
diftime = datetime.strptime(s2, tformat) - datetime.strptime(s1, tformat)

print diftime
1:05:00
```