# Making python dictionary from exiting dictionaries

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have available to me tags and data from a dict that I use in the following way:

```
tags_df_map = zip(tags, data)
append_series = [series for tags,series in tags_df_map if tags['Index'] =='A']
append_tags = [tags['Index'] for tags, series in tags_df_map if tags['Index'] =='A']
series_to_append = dict(zip(append_tags,append_series))
```

Is there an easier and more efficient method in Python to arrive at series_to_append dict? Thanks in advance

Comment: You want dictionary with only one key, value pair?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate the time interval between two time strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096953/how-to-calculate-the-time-interval-between-two-time-strings)

Comment: @jlange, what are you talking about?

Comment: can you show what `tags` and `data` look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
series_to_append = {tag[my_key]: series for tag, series in zip(tags, data) 
                    if tag['Index'] == 'A'}
```

Note that I am using an arbitrary variable `my_key` as the key I'm using to access `tag` for generating the keys of the dictionary comprehension. Before, you had used `tag['Index']` to create the keys for `series_to_append`. This will result in `series_to_append` having only one key (`'A'`), since you are only using values in which `tag['Index']` is equal to `'A'`.

Here is an example of this dictionary comprehension in use:

```
data = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
tags = [{'Index': 'A', 'Key': chr(x+65)} if x % 2 == 0 else {'Index': 'B', 'Key': chr(x+65)} 
        for x in range(7)]

# the original code snippet
tags_df_map = zip(tags, data)
append_series = [series for tag, series in tags_df_map if tag['Index'] =='A']
append_tags = [tag['Index'] for tag, series in tags_df_map if tag['Index'] =='A']
series_to_append = dict(zip(append_tags,append_series))
print(series_to_append)
>> {'A': 6}

{tag['Index']: series for tag, series in zip(tags, data) 
                    if tag['Index'] == 'A'}
>> {'A': 6}

{tag['Key']: series for tag, series in zip(tags, data) 
                    if tag['Index'] == 'A'}
>> {'A': 0, 'C': 2, 'E': 4, 'G': 6}
```

---

Also, as a warning, since it appears that you are using Python 2, using `tags` as a variable name inside your comprehensions will result in the variable `tags` pointing to the last value it was assigned inside the comprehension (rather than the value it pointed to before). That is, assigning a value to a variable inside a list comprehension is treated the same as variable assignment outside of the list comprehension. It's worth noting that this doesn't happen in Python 3 due to how comprehensions are scoped, but it is still usually good practice to not reuse a variable name inside a comprehension unless there is a good reason for doing so.