# Convert local time to UNIX

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I'm trying to get the actual minutes passed every day since 7:00.
I am using mktime to get now_date1 and now_date2 in seconds, and then the plan it's to subtract and divide by 60 to get the minutes.
But I get the following error:

`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'timetuple`'

It's this the correct approach?

Here it's the code

```
import time
import pytz
from datetime import datetime
from time import mktime as mktime

now_date = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/Bucharest'))
now_date1 = now_date.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
now_date2 = now_date.strftime('7:00:00')
# Convert to Unix timestamp
d1_ts = time.mktime(now_date1.timetuple())
```

Comment: `strftime` returns a string. You rather need to convert `now_date2` to a time structure and perform a time delta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strftime` returns a string. Not what you want.

You were pretty close, but there's no need to put `time` in the mix. Just modify your code like this and use time delta from `datetime` (inspired by [How to calculate the time interval between two time strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096953/how-to-calculate-the-time-interval-between-two-time-strings)):

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

now_date = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/Bucharest'))

from datetime import datetime
FMT = '%H:%M:%S'
now_date1 = now_date.strftime(FMT)
now_date2 = now_date.strftime('7:00:00')

tdelta = datetime.strptime(now_date1, FMT) - datetime.strptime(now_date2, FMT)

print(tdelta)
```

I get: `6:40:42` which seems to match since it's 12:42 here.

To get the result in minutes just do:

```
tdelta.seconds//60
```

(note that the dates have only correct hour/time/seconds, the year, month, etc.. are `1900` ... since they're not used)

Comment: Very nice. Now I just need to convert the tdelta into minutes. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this might work:

```
import time
import datetime
from time import mktime as mktime

#current time
now_date = datetime.datetime.now()

#time at 7am
today = datetime.date.today()
now_date2 = datetime.datetime(today.year, today.month, today.day, 7, 0, 0, 0)

#difference in minutes
(now_date - now_date2).days * 24 * 60
```