# Python Time Subtraction Resulting into Time Tuple

Tags: python, datetime, time

I want to subtract 2 times and convert that into a time array.

I consulted this [How to calculate the time interval between two time strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096953/how-to-calculate-the-time-interval-between-two-time-strings). Stating this following code

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
import time

print("Time Subtraction")
FMT = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
time_tuple = (2018, 1, 13, 13, 51, 18, 2, 317, 0)
time2_tuple = (2018, 1, 15, 13, 50, 18, 2, 317, 0)
s1 = time.strftime(FMT, time_tuple)
s2 = time.strftime(FMT, time2_tuple)

tdelta = dt.strptime(s2, FMT) - dt.strptime(s1, FMT)
print(tdelta)
```

The result is:

```
Time Subtraction
1 day, 23:59:00
```

But I want to get a tuple/print that will look like this

```
tuple = (0,0,1,23,59,0,2,317,0)
```

I usually use time not datetime so I am not sure what to do. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tdelta` is a `datetime.timedelta` object, therefore you are printing the string representation of that object. You can get the days, hours, minutes, etc by performing simple arithmetic (since they are stored as fractions-of-days) on the attributes:

```
def days_hours_minutes(delta):
    return delta.days, delta.seconds//3600, (delta.seconds//60)%60
```

You can add as many of these attributes to the tuple as you'd like.