# Django: Calculate with "models.TimeField"

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models

Good day and a happy easter-weekdend,

in Django I'm trying calculate inside my "models.py" with the amounts of multiple TimeField. For example:

```
class Times(models.Model):
    ...
    time_from = model.TimeField()
    time_to = model.TimeField()
    time_break = model.TimeField(default='00:00:00')
    time_all = ...
    ...
```

Let's say my times look like...

- time_from: 08:00:00
- time_to: 14:30:00
- time_break: 00:30:00

... I want to achieve the time of "06:00:00" inside my variable "time_all"

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: what you need, hour difference?

Comment: Have a look into Django's signals if you have all the time components to form the calculation, you can code a signal to do the algorithm and then save the time_all value into the datebase. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/signals/

Comment: @ThomasJohn: Yes, I need the difference, but in hours, minutes and seconds

Comment: @LewisHepburn: Thanks, I will look into this topic!

Answer (score 0):

```
class Times(models.Model):
    ...
    time_from = model.TimeField()
    time_to = model.TimeField()
    time_break = model.TimeField(default='00:00:00')
    time_all = ...
    ...


def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
   print(self.time_from," aaaaaaaaaaaaaa " ,self.time_to) 
   self.time_all = "blah blah " #do what ever you need here 
   super(Model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Use any calculation or formatting before save. You can also try this with [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/) if you need to do before or after save.

For time string difference, please refer this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096953/how-to-calculate-the-time-interval-between-two-time-strings)

Comment: I'm trying to get the value of  my models.TimeField() into a time string variable but it doesn't seem to work. With "dt.datetime.strptime(str(timeFrom), '%H:%M:%S')" I get the response: time data '<..TimeField>' does not match format '%H:%M%:S'

Answer (score 0):

If you want calculate many TimeField, you must have to convert temporarily yours fields to datetime and timedelta.
So, like this :

```
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta


time_from = time(8, 0)
time_to = time(14, 30)
time_break = time(0, 30)

t1 = datetime.combine(date.today(), time_to)
t2 = datetime.combine(date.min, time_from) - datetime.min
t3 = datetime.combine(date.min, time_break). - datetime.min

diff = (t1 - t2) - t3
convert_to_time = diff.time()

>>> t1
datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 25, 14, 30)

>>> t2
datetime.timedelta(seconds=28800)

>>> t3
datetime.timedelta(seconds=1800)

>>> diff
datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 25, 6, 0)

>>> diff.time()
datetime.time(6, 0)
>>> print(diff.time())
06:00:00
```

I hope so help you.