# Can time delta help me show when an aircraft is overdue?

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.8

Is there a code to depict a timer to demonstrate an aircraft is 30 minutes late from its original arrival time? For example, original time of arrival is 7:35 pm and now it's 8:05 pm. Will TIMEDELTA help me with this based on the original arrival time 7:35 pm? What I am looking for in the end result will print out ("Aircraft overdue") or the text change red to alert.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you don't need to do anything very complicated here. Just subtract two `datetime` objects and you will end up with a `timedelta` object.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

scheduled_arrival = datetime(2020, 6, 9, 17, 35)
actual_arrival = datetime(2020, 6, 9, 18, 5)
delta = actual_arrival - scheduled_arrival

if delta > timedelta(0): # cannot compare to bare 0, need to create timedelta object
    print("Late!")
    # If you want to be more specific...
    print(delta) # '00:30:00'
    print(f"Minutes: {int(delta.total_seconds() // 60)}") # 30
else:
    print("On time or early")
```

See more here if you need to convert strings to `datetime` objects: [How to calculate the time interval between two time strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096953/how-to-calculate-the-time-interval-between-two-time-strings/18388070)