# How can we see uptime bot at discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to make a commands showing uptime of the both, for example `Online Time: 1h 10m 15s`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.py Uptime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62483161/discord-py-uptime)

Answer (score 2):

You would save the time when the bot is started and then compare it to the time you called the command.

```py
import datetime as dt

# after you initialize bot itself
bot.launch_time = dt.datetime.utcnow()

@bot.command()
async def uptime(ctx):
    delta_uptime = dt.datetime.utcnow() - bot.launch_time
    hours, remainder = divmod(int(delta_uptime.total_seconds()), 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
    days, hours = divmod(hours, 24)
    await ctx.reply(f"Online Time: {days}d, {hours}h, {minutes}m, {seconds}s")
```