# convert a time string to time

Tags: python, datetime, time, format

I have two time strings for start and end, as an example:

```py
start = "9:30:00"
end = "11:14:00"
```

I want to subtract start from end to get the duration.

I have tried

```
new_start = datetime.strptime(start, '%H:%M:%S').strftime("%H:%M:%S")
new_end = datetime.strptime(end, '%H:%M:%S').strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

I still get

> unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: here is the answer i guess you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096953/how-to-calculate-the-time-interval-between-two-time-strings

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate the time interval between two time strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096953/how-to-calculate-the-time-interval-between-two-time-strings)

Comment: Sure the subtraction order is appropriate to get the duration as intervall: "subtract start for end" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the following way to subtract two time strings

```
     from datetime import datetime

     t1 = '10:33:26'
     t2 = '11:15:49'
     FMT = '%H:%M:%S'  # time format
     
     subtractedTime = datetime.strptime(t2, FMT) - datetime.strptime(t1, FMT)
```

Comment: Comments start with a `#` in Python  ;-)

Comment: Thanks @MrFuppes for reminding me.

Comment: @PrashantBalotra You could [edit] and fix. At least reference the source which already answered: [How to calculate the time interval between two time strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096953/how-to-calculate-the-time-interval-between-two-time-strings). In the future please flag the question as __duplicate__.

Answer (score 1):

To convert a time string to a time, use `strptime`.

...and that's it.

Don't convert the times to strings again with `strftime` before you have done your calculations with them.

Comment: Thanks- that kind of worked using 
new_start = datetime.strptime(start, '%H:%M:%S') 
            
new_end = datetime.strptime(end, '%H:%M:%S')  

That produced This I expected to see 39 minutes
1900-01-01 09:30:00 1900-01-01 10:09:00 -1 day, 23:21:00

Comment: Looks like you subtracted them in the wrong order?!

Comment: yep I think I got it Thanks

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers